# How can I set NODE_ENV=production on Windows?

Tags: node.js, express

In Ubuntu it's quite simple; I can run the application using:

```
$ NODE_ENV=production node myapp/app.js
```

However, this doesn't work on Windows. Is there a configuration file where I can set the attribute?

Comment: For a multiplatform solution you can find the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57509175/11127383

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set NODE\_ENV to production/development in OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198310/how-to-set-node-env-to-production-development-in-os-x)

Answer (score 667, accepted):

Current versions of Windows use Powershell as the default shell, so use:

```
$env:NODE_ENV="production"
```

Per @jsalonen's answer below. If you're in CMD (which is no longer maintained), use

```
set NODE_ENV=production
```

This should be executed in the command prompt where you intend to run your Node.js application.

The above line would set the environment variable NODE_ENV for the command prompt where you execute the command.

To set environment variables globally so they persist beyond just the single command prompt, you can find the tool from System in Control Panel (or by typing 'environment' into the search box in the start menu).

Comment: This form of configuring an environment variable did not work for me. Instead I used as described by @jsalonen and worked perfectly.

Comment: For anyone still struggling with this: `set NODE_ENV=production && node app`. More conveniently configure your `package.json` accordingly: `"scripts": { "start": "set NODE_ENV=production && node app" }`.

Comment: For me on Windows 8 this works `set NODE_ENV production`. Your example doesn't work on my machine.

Comment: @WooCaSh sounds like you might be in PowerShell in that case, I don't think they changed command prompt's behavior in Win8

Comment: @JaniHartikainen might be true. I use console from WebStorm. Thanks for advice.

Comment: is there anything returns after you type in this command? I didn't get anything at all after I type in this command. (I am trying to run a node project on Windows too)

Comment: @ShuruiLiu the command will not output anything, but you can type `echo %NODE_ENV%` to check its current value.

Comment: Heads up: "set NODE_ENV=production && " adds a trailing space to the variable. I needed "set NODE_ENV=production&& " to avoid the additional space which breaks node apps like Ghost.

Comment: @Amberlamps that is not a good solution because the NODE_ENV is then just hardcoded for all machines; the real goal is to change the env by machine using an env variable or to pass in the value at the command line, not hardcode it in the package.json file.

Comment: @AlexMills that's why you can add more than one "scripts" item. simply add one for "debug" or whatever you wanna call it and run that on other machines

Comment: using this to switch from development to testing is inconvenient because once you use "set NODE_ENV=testing&& server" then you can't just hit ctrl+c and run node server expecting NODE_ENV to default to 'development' because you just set it to 'testing' for the terminal session. Would be great if node had a --env option that just overrides NODE_ENV temporarily.

Comment: I think using `cross-env` is the better solution to this problem if your team works on mixed operating systems. Answer from @MoOx would be my pick as an answer to this question.

Comment: Thanks  @daw. Your comments should be added to the original answer

Comment: The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.

Comment: Thanks @daw again and set NODE_ENV='production' && does not work either b/c the quote will also be read into NODE_ENV

Comment: @daw you actually saved me from wasting more time. thanks

Answer (score 369):

I just found a nice Node.js package that can help a lot to define environment variables using a unique syntax, cross platform.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env

It allow you to write something like this:

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=production my-command
```

Which is pretty convenient! No Windows or Unix specific commands any more!

Comment: While the first answer is true. I think this answer is most reliable and should be used

Comment: Simple and perfectly solves my problem. I was able to build on Linux only. This solved both, Linux and Windows.

Comment: This answer deserves more love, should be the accepted one :)

Comment: This is the best answer for me also

Comment: Worked like magic, thanks.

My error was `'NODE_ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: we need to boost this answer because it makes more sense than the first one.

Comment: It's still not work for me, sad

Answer (score 188):

In PowerShell:

```
$env:NODE_ENV="production"
```

Comment: p.s.: don't forget the $ and the quotes ;)

Comment: `set NODE_ENV=production` did not work for me in powershell but this did. Thanks!

Comment: Struggled a bit to get this to work from Powershell within Visual Studio Code.  Thought I'd leave solution here.  I was attempting to run a "Gulp" command, while ensuring correct env value was set.  This is what wound up working for me: `$env:NODE_ENV="development"; gulp runMytask`.  Note the semi-colon in there.  The gulp file can use conditional logic on process.env.NODE_ENV.  Unless you set it, it will be undefined.

Comment: Only this solution work for me with windows 10 and webpack 3.8.1

Comment: This works perfect. But, the `cross-env NODE_ENV=production` option is really a better solution if running npm commands from package.json that require the env to be set. It's too easy to leave the env set on dev/prod after using the $env:NODE_ENV option

Answer (score 176):

It would be ideal if you could set parameters on the same line as your call to start Node.js on Windows. Look at the following carefully, and run it exactly as stated:

You have these two options:

1. At the command line:

   ```
   set NODE_ENV=production&&npm start
   ```

   or

   ```
   set NODE_ENV=production&&node index.js
   ```
2. **The trick for it to work on Windows is you need to remove the whitespace before and after the "&&".** Configured your package.json file with start_windows (see below) below. Then Run "npm run start_windows" at the command line.

   ```
   //package.json

   "scripts": {
     "start": "node index.js"
     "start_windows": "set NODE_ENV=production&&node index.js"
   }
   ```

Comment: Would DEF like to know how to get it to work this way.

Comment: try it out and leave your feedback

Comment: Worked for me. Had to remove the whitespace though "set NODE_ENV=production&&nodemon server.js"

Comment: @SC_Chupacabra probably don't want to be in production using nodemon, maybe "set NODE_ENV=development&&nodemon server.js" is better :)

Comment: Wish I had read down this far before trying the answer above, would have saved me some time. :\

Comment: On a vaguely related note I found that && didn't work as expected on windows when chaining multiple commands together. If in doubt try using | instead

Comment: really surprised that having no white space fixed my error!

Comment: this worked for me on windows 10 64bit machine from both cmd and power-shell

Comment: It is not necessary to remove the whitespace after the `&&`. You could use `set NODE_ENV=production&& node index.js` Reason: The whitespace between `production` and `&&` is interprated as part of the NODE_ENV. You could use single quotes and whitespaces to solve this problem as well. So this is also valid and should work: `set 'NODE_ENV=production' && node index.js`

Comment: Removing WHITESPACE before and after && worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 41):

You can use

```
npm run env NODE_ENV=production
```

It is probably the best way to do it, because it's compatible on both Windows and Unix.

From the [npm run-script documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script):

> The env script is a special built-in command that can be used to list environment variables that will be available to the script at runtime. If an "env" command is defined in your package it will take precedence over the built-in.

Comment: How can we execute another command with the variable set? This does not seem to work: npm run env NODE_ENV=production && echo $NODE_ENV. Probably they are executed in two different shells?

Comment: From what I can see, this doesn't work at all. From the docs itself, It's only **listing** environment variables, not setting them.

Comment: Does not work for me. It list vars, show the var you specify, but on runtime, var is not ok in process.env.YOUR_VAR...

Comment: @JonasKello You would use this: `npm run env NODE_ENV=production -- node -e 'console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)'` The `--` is **mandatory**. Replace `node -e 'console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)'` with whatever command you want.

Comment: Tried this with this command: `npm run env NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 --  node --inspect ./etc/http-req-standalone.js` and ... nothing happened. I'm not sure this method works on windows.

Comment: This method does not work on windows, but replacing `--` with `&&` should work.

`npm run env NODE_ENV=production && node -e 'console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)'`

Comment: This worked for me using [cmder](https://cmder.net/) (which essentially uses cmd.exe / PowerShell under the hood) on Windows: `npm run env NODE_ENV=development -- node app.js`

Answer (score 24):

I wrote a module [win-node-env](https://github.com/laggingreflex/win-node-env) with which you can run your command just like you would in *nix.

```
NODE_ENV=production node myapp/app.js
```

It works by creating a `NODE_ENV.cmd` that sets the `NODE_ENV` environment variable and spawns a child process with the rest of the command and its args.

Just install it (globally), and run your npm script commands, it should automatically make them work.

```
npm install -g win-node-env
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for! to run with npm scripts, and it even works with other node cli tools like jest. So "set NODE_ENV=debug & cls & jest..." became "cls & NODE_ENV=debug jest"

Answer (score 15):

My experience using Node.js on Windows 7 64-bit in Visual Studio 2013 is that you need to use

```
setx NODE_ENV development
```

from a cmd window. AND you have to restart Visual Studio in order for the new value to be recognized.

The set syntax only lasts for the duration of the cmd window in which it is set.

Simple test in Node.js:

```
console.log('process.env.NODE_ENV = ' + process.env.NODE_ENV);
```

It returns 'undefined' when using set, and it will return 'development' if using setx and restarting Visual Studio.

Comment: `cmd` -- not powershell? Ugh, come on windows, get it together.

Comment: your remark about restart of VS code was really useful!

Answer (score 14):

If you are using Visual Studio with NTVS, you can set the environment variables on the project properties page:

[image: Visual Studio NTVS Project Properties]

As you can see, the Configuration and Platform dropdowns are disabled (I haven't looked too far into why this is), but if you edit your `.njsproj` file as follows:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <Environment>NODE_ENV=development</Environment>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <Environment>NODE_ENV=production</Environment>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

The 'Debug / Release' dropdown will then control how the variable is set before starting Node.js.

Answer (score 13):

Here is the non-command line method:

In Windows 7 or 10, type environment into the start menu search box, and select Edit the system environment variables.

Alternatively, navigate to Control Panel\System and Security\System, and click Advanced system settings

This should open up the System properties dialog box with the Advanced tab selected.  At the bottom, you will see an Environment Variables... button.  Click this.

[image: System Dialog Box]

The Environment Variables Dialog Box will open.

[image: Environment Variable Dialog Box]

At the bottom, under System variables, select New...This will open the New System Variable dialog box.

[image]

Enter the variable name and value, and click OK.

You will need to close all cmd prompts and restart your server for the new variable to be available to process.env.  If it still doesn't show up, restart your machine.

Comment: Thank you! I had done all this but it wasn't working until I restarted the server.

Comment: Question - will next.js be able to read these windows system environment variables?  We're deploying to Azure using CI/CD pipelines and want to take advantage of the Configuration Settings in an Azure Web App, which your code (at least in .NET) can read just like reading windows system environment variables without any code changes.  Hope this makes sense :|

Answer (score 10):

if you are using vs code terminal you have to use this command

```
$env:NODE_ENV="production"
```

Comment: This also works for the Windows Powershell Terminal. Thank you @kukab.

Answer (score 9):

To run your application in PowerShell (since `&&` is disallowed):

```
($env:NODE_ENV="production") -and (node myapp/app.js)
```

Note that the text output of what the server's doing is suppressed, and I am not sure if that's fixable. (Expanding on @jsalonen's answer.)

Comment: It didn't work for me: `"debug-windows": "($env:NODE_ENV=\"dev\") -and (node src/dequeue.js)"`

Answer (score 9):

Just to clarify, and for anyone else that may be pulling their hair out...

If you are using **git bash on Windows**, `set node_env=production&& node whatever.js` **does not seem to work**. Instead, use the native cmd. Then, using `set node_env=production&& node whatever.js`works as expected.

My use case:

I develop on Windows because my workflow is *a lot* faster, but I needed to make sure that my application's development-specific middleware were not firing in the production environment.

Answer (score 8):

first in powershell type

```
$env:NODE_ENV="production"
```

then type

```
node fileName.js
```

It will work perfectly displaying all the outputs.

Answer (score 3):

For Windows

set NODE_ENV=development && react-scripts start

For Ubuntu, Linux, macOs

NODE_ENV=development react-scripts start

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to people with similar issues. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: How it answers the question? This is exactly the way to rewrite the command in windows. I don't see what other explanation is needed here.

Answer (score 2):

For *multiple* environment variables, an `.env` file is more convenient:

```bash
# .env.example, committed to repo
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USER=root
DB_PASS=s1mpl3
```

```bash
# .env, private, .gitignore it
DB_HOST=real-hostname.example.com
DB_USER=real-user-name
DB_PASS=REAL_PASSWORD
```

It's easy to use with [`dotenv-safe`](https://github.com/rolodato/dotenv-safe):

1. Install with `npm install --save-dev dotenv-safe`.
2. Include it in your code (best at the start of the `index.js`) and directly use it with the [`process.env` command](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env):

```js
require('dotenv').load()
console.log(process.env.DB_HOST)
```

Don't forget to [**ignore the `.env` file** in your VCS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695461/is-it-safe-to-use-the-same-ignores-file-for-git-mercurial-and-bazaar).

Your program then fails fast if a variable "defined" in `.env.example` is unset either as an environment variable or in `.env`.

Comment: .env files are only convenient for secrets and add an extra step of complexity when setting up when assigning new people to a project or applying changes to them.

Comment: @coiso Without a generic, common place, where do you put *many* env variables? Either in a script file or in an IDE dependent setting, you're even more bound to specific tools. This makes integrating new team members even more harder, I think.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are using GITBASH terminal 
`"set NODE_ENV=production"` 
will not work, what can you do is type 
"export `NODE_ENV=production"`

Comment: I get an error: `'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`

Comment: Try using it with 'set' instead of 'export'

Answer (score 2):

```
set NODE_ENV=production & node server.js
```

Answer (score 1):

Restart VS code if the NODE_ENV or any other environment variable is not providing correct value. This should work after restart.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the best method I could see is as follows.

```
"set-env-qa": "npm run env APP_ENV=qa",
"start:qa": "npm run set-env-qa && react-native start",
```

This will make sure we get the correct env setup for the programs. replace react-native-start with whichever next command you want.

Answer (score 0):

For git bash terminal in vscode it is:export NODE_ENV, instead of set NODE_ENV

Comment: In addition to this being a question specifically about Windows shells, this was already given as an answer [5 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51861824/1255289)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can install the next plugin now that your commands are operational.

```
npm install -g win-node-env
```

Answer (score -1):

this will not set a variable but it's usefull in many cases.  I will not recommend using this for production, but it should be okay if you're playing around with npm.

```
npm install --production
```

Answer (score -1):

I used npm script for running a gulp task without "&&"

NODE_ENV=testcases npm run seed-db

Answer (score -1):

In Windows 10 I have used  `$env:NODE_ENV="Production"`

This worked on my vscode terminal. But if your server is listening first need to stop and set your env variable and start the app again. This way it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking to set environment variable and run npm script in the same line then use:

```
$env:BASE_URL="https://example.com"; npm run __your_npm_script__
```

Answer (score -3):

It seems that

```
{
   "start_windows": "set NODE_ENV=test"
}
```

is not working for me. I'm currently trying this on my Windows machine. When I hit:

```
npm run start_windows
```

it would execute on the console without errors but when I try to echo

```
echo %NODE_ENV%
```

nothing comes out of it, meaning it does not exist and it wasn't set at all...

Comment: You've probably overcome this, but your last line would be: `ps aux | grep NODE_ENV` But, you're also not running with the "start_windows" script. Other answers point out that you'd need to do something like: `"set NODE_ENV=test&& node ./index.js"`. Finally, you're setting the envar for that particular session, on that terminal. So, really, your echo or more proper "ps aux" op is invalid. You'd just log-out the setting in your "index.js" or "app.js", whatever your entry is: `console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);`.
Anyway, I hope that helps more than a downvote.

Comment: This is not an answer, but a question.