# "NODE_ENV" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable command or batch file

Tags: windows, node.js

I'm trying to setup an environment for a Node.js app. but I'm getting this error every time.

> "NODE_ENV" is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable command or batch file.

What does this mean and how can I solve this problem?

I'm using Windows and also tried `set NODE_ENV=development` but had no luck.

Answer (score 421, accepted):

It sounds like your error comes from an attempt to run something like this (which works in Linux):

```
NODE_ENV=development node foo.js
```

the equivalent in Windows would be:

```
SET NODE_ENV=development & node foo.js
```

running in the same command shell. You mentioned `SET NODE_ENV` did not work, but was not clear how/when you executed it.

Comment: thanks Jim, i used it in command line and removed from package.json file. but i ran into another after that. looks like node modules are not fully supported by windows. got another error with bcrypt and gyp.

Comment: not a expert here, but bcrypt shows support for windows, but does require openSSL, not sure if that helps.  If not, might want to post a new question since the scenario has changed a bit.

Comment: While this is indeed working, I think @Susan-stack gave the correct answer - a cross platform solution and not changing the line to work on windows but break other OS.

Comment: upvoted Susan's answer - original response predated the cross-env module

Comment: @krozero try installing all packages again  that might help you

Comment: @JimO'Neil, okay so it seems that in a Windows machine you cannot set `NODE_ENV=test` or `NODE_ENV=development` inside of the `"scripts"` section of a `package.json` file, is that about the size of it?

Comment: @justabuzz I like to keep external dependencies to minimum and I know what's the only OS in use. this is the answer for me.

Comment: The correct answer is https://stackoverflow.com/a/33755445/3728901 , use `&` , not separating in 2 lines.

Answer (score 630):

I wrote a module for this: [win-node-env](https://github.com/laggingreflex/win-node-env).

It creates a `NODE_ENV.cmd` that sets the `NODE_ENV` environment variable and spawns a child process with the rest of the command and its args.

Just install it (globally), and run your npm script commands, it should automatically make them work.

```
npm install -g win-node-env
```

Comment: It works! And I didn't have to change any commands. This is the answer.

Comment: this is the easiest aswer

Comment: How can I add custom variables to you script?

Comment: @ivan-ivory The first variable (i.e. NODE_ENV) has to stay the same (otherwise it'll have to be an entirely separate script). And as for adding custom variables after it (i.e. NODE_ENV=dev SOME_VAR=val) I'll have to modify the logic of the script to parse more variables from process.argv. I've been thinking about it but don't have the time. Feel free to make a pull request.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I'm getting: 
> NODE_ENV=development node_modules/.bin/nodemon --ignore ./public/tones/ --exec babel-node server/index.js

'node_modules' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @RodrigoGarcia Try just `NODE_ENV=development nodemon --ignore ./public/tones/ --exec babel-node server/index.js` ("node_modules/.bin" is added to the path automatically when executing any npm script)

Comment: @ivan-ivory I've just added support for custom variables (as long as they come *after* the first variable, as mentioned before), as well as some more commonly used variables (like `ENV`, `DEBUG`, `PORT`), and paved the way to add more in future easily if required. Please check out the latest version.

Comment: thank you, without this, we wouldn't had done the project

Comment: Good documented answer

Comment: perfect one. but i would be better if you discussed what are you doing there

Comment: This is a good approach if you cannot change the source repo, however if you're creating a package that others are likely to use and want to make it cross-platform, you should use [Susan's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37131308/195835).

Comment: Superb answer. I can recommend it.

Comment: Didn't work
`Note: This command was run via npm module 'win-node-env'`
`Error: No command was given`

Comment: @PwrSrg Could you [file an issue](https://github.com/laggingreflex/win-node-env/issues) with more details please? I'd love to look into it. "No command given" to me seems like you're just running `NODE_ENV=development` without any succeding command like `nodemon`, is that the case at all?

Answer (score 287):

for windows use `&` in between command also. Like,

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "SET NODE_ENV=development & nodemon app/app.js",
  }
```

Comment: The command works but the value of `NODE_ENV` will be 'development ' (the white space between 't' and '&' will be contained by `NODE_ENV`)

Comment: exactly what @roroinpho21 says. now I have to `.trim()` the value later to make `process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production'` work. Anyway to avoid this in a oneliner?

Comment: People who couldn't make it work,
    `"test-unit": "SET NODE_ENV=test & mocha --require co-mocha 'test.js'"` **wrong** `"test-unit": "SET NODE_ENV=test & mocha --require co-mocha test.js"` **true**. _You need to remove the_ `' '` _around the js file._

Comment: This does exactly what you want if you're trying to run npm start to set the production mode to production.

Comment: This is actual a better answer than the accepted one.
I didn't face any issues like the above comments :)

Comment: SET REACT_APP_STAGE=prod&SET GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false&react-scripts build
 worked for me

Comment: `NODE_ENV=dev&nodemon src/index.js`

Comment: muy util y simple, gracias. para mi esta es la mejor respuesta!

Answer (score 194):

1. `npm install --save-dev "cross-env"` module.
2. modify the code as `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node foo.js`.
   Then you can run the like `npm run build`.

Comment: Please don't forget to include `cross-env` to the dependencies in `package.json`

Comment: cross-env best answer!

Comment: The library is here: https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env -- and that page says to include cross-dev in devDependencies ```npm install --save-dev cross-env```; this also helps with the error ```'env' is not recognized as an internal or external command``` when the npm script said ```env VARNAME=varvalue && ...``` (just remove env and insert cross-env instead). No need for developers to install something globally or to have different npm scripts for different platforms!

Comment: This should probably be the accepted answer. It's a platform agnostic solution

Comment: Agreed. This answer covers any env variables and not just node env variables. Best answer!

Comment: Of course, if you want to use `cross-env` in a production startup context, then that package needs to be in the `dependencies`, not `devDependencies`...

Answer (score 73):

Use [win-node-env](https://github.com/laggingreflex/win-node-env), For using it just run below command on your `cmd` or `power shell` or `git bash`:

```
npm install -g win-node-env
```

After it everything is like Linux.

Answer (score 51):

I had the same problem and on windows platform and i just ran the below command

```
npm install -g win-node-env
```

and everything works normally

Comment: Worked like a charm, needed this for a project where we are developing across multiple platforms (Mac and Windows).

Comment: What does this do exactly?

Comment: please read here  https://www.npmjs.com/package/win-node-env?activeTab=readme

Answer (score 44):

```
set NODE_ENV=production & nodemon app/app.js
```

will cause NODE_ENV to **contain a space** at the end:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production'; //false
process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production '; //true
```

As mentioned in a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9250168/977206), use this instead:

```
NODE_ENV=production&& nodemon app/app.js
```

Comment: This has been a life saver!

Comment: You're the man, worked perfectly

Comment: set NODE_ENV=production & nodemon app/app.js perfact

Answer (score 39):

Changing your scripts to accommodate Windows is a royal pain. Trying to figure out the appropriate Windows translations and maintaining 2 sets of scripts is no way to live your life.

It's much easier to configure npm to use bash on Windows and your scripts will run as is.

Simply run `npm config set script-shell "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"`. Make sure the path to the bash executable is correct for your machine. ***You'll likely need to start a new instance of the terminal for the change to take effect.***

The screenshot below illustrates the benefit.

1. npm ERR! when trying to run script initially.
2. Script modified for Windows use runs but doesn't show the return message.
3. After updating npm config to use bash, the script runs and returns the appropriate message.

[image: Getting npm scripts to run as is in Windows]

Comment: YES! Just what I needed! Who wants to `npm install -g more-cr*p` anyway?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Using git bash for windows is SO much better than `cmd`. There are definitely other options such as directly messing with cygwin or using WSL, but so many node.js scripts want to use shell, that this just MAKES SENSE. Also, [yarn has a similar config option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58188828/57611).

Answer (score 17):

For those who uses Git Bash and having issues with `npm run <script>`,

Just set npm to use Git Bash to run scripts

`npm config set script-shell "C:\\Program Files\\git\\bin\\bash.exe"` (change the path according to your installation)

And then npm will run scripts with Git Bash, so such usages like `NODE_ENV=` will work properly.

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me since it's an easy fix. I cloned a repository which was developed in WINDOWS but I am using MACOS.

If you are using windows use SET as prefix:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "SET NODE_ENV=development && nodemon index.js",
  },
```

But if you are using MacOS **remove the SET keyword** and use :

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development && nodemon index.js",
  },
```

So in a **nutshell**

if you are using windows use **SET** prefix before your run scripts and **remove SET** from MacOS (probably LINUX also) as shown above.

Comment: @Ishan_Kesharwani space is important before && in windows environment and in this example NODE_ENV is "development ", to remove space after development string, statements in dev should be separate with just && without space.

Comment: in mac it worked without `&&` what worked for me is `NODE_ENV=development nodemon app.mjs`

Answer (score 8):

you can use this

```
"scripts": {
   "start:dev": "nodemon server.js",
   "start:prod": "SET NODE_ENV=production & nodemon 
   server.js"
},
```

or you can install this

```
 npm install -g win-node-env
```

and you can run NODE_ENV without SET

```
 "start:prod": "NODE_ENV=production nodemon server.js"
```

Answer (score 7):

Do this it will definitely work

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "SET NODE_ENV=production && node server"
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
NODE_ENV=development & node [your file name here]
```

or

```
SET NODE_ENV=development & node [your file name here]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can solve this if you're using "Yarn Packager" by the following command:

```
yarn global add win-node-env
```

Answer (score 4):

```
npm install -S cross-env
```

Worked for me

Answer (score 4):

If anyone else came here like me trying to find a solution for the error:

```
'env' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

The reason I got this is that I was migrating an angular solution from a mac development machine over to a windows 10 desktop.  This is how I resolved it.

1. run `npm install --save-dev cross-env`
2. go into my package.json file and change all the script references from `env <whatever>` to `cross-env <whatever>`

Then my commands like: `npm run start:some_random_environment_var` now run fine on Windows 10.

Comment: For Windows users to just switch to Bash is a bit mush, especially when the rest just works. 

This is a good solution that worked for me.

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer. `cross-env` works no matter what OS you are on.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the answers up there didn't help me..

What helped me was `NODE_ENV=production&& nodemon app/app.js`

Take note of the space.
Good luck.

Comment: This worked for me in Windows 10, Node v14.18.1.

Answer (score 3):

For windows 
**open git bash** and try

`NODE_ENV=production node app.js`

Comment: It does work in Git Bash (mintty) when used directly.

But when I run the same command from `npm <scripts_entry>`, I get an error with different phrasing but equivalent meaning: it treats env var name as an executable.

Comment: @AndreyMikhaylov-lolmaus `npm run <script>` uses Windows cmd as default to run commands. You can set it to use Git Bash. `npm config set script-shell "C:\\Program Files\\git\\bin\\bash.exe"` And then `npm run` will use Git Bash to run scripts.

Answer (score 3):

For windows you can do it like

```
"scripts": {
    "start:prod" : "SET NODE_ENV=production & nodemon app.js",
    "start:dev" : "SET NODE_ENV=development & nodemon app.js"
},
```

Answer (score 2):

**set the script "test"** inside the "package.json" file :

FOR EXAMPLE:

**In Windows**;
"test": "SET NODE_ENV=test & jest",

**In Linux/Mac**;
"test": "NODE_ENV=test jest",

Answer (score 2):

set `NODE_ENV=**production&** nodemon server.js`
& must be joined because if you put space between production and & then
NODE_ENV will contain space in last like this 'production '
So just remove space between production and & and add space after **&**

Answer (score 2):

You can use this syntax (using "cross-env") ->

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=prod node dist/main
```

Answer (score 1):

**process.env.NODE_ENV** is adding a **white space** do this

```
process.env.NODE_ENV.trim() == 'production'
```

Answer (score 1):

> `"set NODE_ENV=production&& nodemon server.js"` this one works for me.

Comment: How does this differ from the other 21 answers already here?

Answer (score 1):

**below code for windows**

```
"start": "SET NODE_ENV=development & nodemon app.js",
"prod": "SET NODE_ENV=production & node app.js"
```

Answer (score 1):

For linux environment:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js",
    "start:prod": "NODE_ENV=production nodemon server.js",
}
```

For windows environemnt:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js",
    "start:prod": "SET NODE_ENV=production & nodemon server.js",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On a windows platform

> ($env:NODE_ENV="environmentName") -and (node file.js)

Kill the terminal( Ctrl + C) then run the file

> node file.js

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Powershell as your terminal by any chance, try Using Git-Bash for the same.

```
NODE_ENV=development node foo.js
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this

> NODE_ENV =development node server.js

Answer (score 0):

```
"scripts": {
"start": "SET NODE_ENV=staging&nodemon index",
"production": "SET NODE_ENV=production&nodemon index"}
```

in package.json. Don't give space between the env name and nodemon

Answer (score 0):

For those of you running into this with npm scripts on windows, **even though you are running your scripts in git bash, npm is still using `cmd` as its script shell.**

Set git bash as npm's script shell and you are good to go.

**See my answer here:**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76713342/10547719