# NODE_ENV is not recognised as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, express, package.json

I am developing in node.js and wanted to take into account both production and development environment. I found out that setting NODE_ENV while running the node.js server does the job. However when I try to set it in package.json script it gives me the error:

> NODE_ENV is not recognised as an internal or external command

Below is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "NODEAPT",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=development node ./bin/server",
    "qa2": "NODE_ENV=qa2  node ./bin/server",
    "prod": "NODE_ENV=production node ./bin/server"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.15.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.13.4",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "morgan": "~1.7.0",
    "oracledb": "^1.11.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
  }
}
```

I run my node server as: `npm run qa2` for example.

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated

Comment: what operating system are you using

Comment: I am developing on windows os. Does it matter.

Comment: yes os matters. for windows it is `SET NODE_ENV=development node ./bin/server`

Comment: use GULP if you have multiple environments and some other global variables which vary for each environment

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["NODE\_ENV" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable command or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928013/node-env-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-comman/40967643#40967643)

Answer (score 62):

Since you are using `windows operating system.`, the command varies from the unix system command that you are using.

In windows you have to modify you script as.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": " SET NODE_ENV=development &  node ./bin/server",
    "qa2": "SET NODE_ENV=qa2 & node ./bin/server",
    "prod": "SET NODE_ENV=production & node ./bin/server"
  },
```

Use `SET` and then an `&` after that.

However using `cross-env` npm package for cross platform stability is recommeded.

Install it like `npm install -S cross-env`

```
"scripts": {
    "start": " cross-env NODE_ENV=development &  node ./bin/server",
    "qa2": "cross-env NODE_ENV=qa2 & node ./bin/server",
    "prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production & node ./bin/server"
  },
```

Comment: Use it as a dev dependency instead of a normal dependency. So, "npm install -D cross-env".

Comment: the "npm install -S cross-env" worked for me in windows. thanks a lot

Answer (score 15):

I can suggest cross platform sollution. It's done with the help of the [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) npm package. Your script section would look like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "globals" : "npm i -g cross-env",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development &  node ./bin/server",
    "qa2": "cross-env NODE_ENV=qa2 & node ./bin/server",
    "prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production & node ./bin/server"
  }
```

So you run once:

```
npm run globals // to install global dependencies
```

Then you're free to use your scripts both on linux and windows(mac?).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think I will go with the other answer.

Comment: Using cross-env is HIGHLY recommended, because you never know who is going to try to run your code. Other developers, servers, virtual boxes, Macs, Linux machines, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes this can be fixed by using [win-node-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/win-node-env) if your running on windows, For using it just run the below command.

```
npm install -g win-node-env
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run into this problem in 2021, install `cross-env` as a dev dependency by running `npm i -D cross-env`.

Then, modify your command in the package.json file thus:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node ./bin/server",
    "qa2": "cross-env NODE_ENV=qa2  node ./bin/server",
    "prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node ./bin/server"
  },
```