# “NODE_ENV” is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable command or batch file

Tags: node.js, windows, windows-10

I'm trying to setup an environment. However, I'm getting the following error every time:

> `NODE_ENV" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable command or batch file.`

When I added the set before `NODE_ENV` it showed me only this:

```
set NODE_ENV=development nodemon -w src --exec "babel-node src --presets es2015,stage-0"
```

Comment: The `cross-env` package is helpful for this

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["NODE\_ENV" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable command or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928013/node-env-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-comman/40967643#40967643)

Answer (score 5):

In package.json please add below line and try,

```
"build": "SET NODE_ENV=production webpack"
```

If no luck then add below dependency,

```
"npm i cross-env"
```

and in package.json,

```
"start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node server.dev.js", "serve": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server.prod.js"
```

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes setting `SET NODE_ENV=...` doesn't solve your issue. Then you should run `npm install -g win-node-env`