# Debugger issue in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-debugger

I am trying to the attached debugger to the React Native app.
I am using the React Native tool extension for React Native debugging.

as I am new to React Native I am kind of stuck as I am not able to debug.
I am not sure why it's showing 8082 and not 8081. My metro bundler is showing in PORT 8081.

Note: I am using an iOS simulator to test.

Is anything I am doing wrong or missing something?

**Please suggest if more information needed.**

[image]

Comment: Are you running on multiple device?

Comment: Dear Sandesh, do you try to change the default PORT? what's your ReactJS, ReactNative, and Debugger version?

Answer (score 2):

For Fixing this issue let's follow the below steps and run your project by the given commands:

1. Change the metro default port with adding an environment variable:

   ```
   export RCT_METRO_PORT=9095
   ```

   ⚠: if you are on Windows, firstly, please do [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48966524/6877799).
2. Navigate to the `ios` folder of your project and edit:

   ```
   ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-Core/React/RCTDefines.h
   ```

   Find all `8081` or `8082` and change them to `9095`, always you find them in defining of `RCT_METRO_PORT`
3. Do number two exactly for:

   ```
   ios/Pods/Headers/Private/React-Core/React/RCTDefines.h
   ```
4. Also in the `ios` folder of your project change this file too:

   ```
   ios/Kelaket.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
   ```

   Find the two `RCT_METRO_PORT:=8081` and change both of them to `RCT_METRO_PORT:=9095`
5. Change the `default` of `yargs.option` to `9095` in the:

   ```
   node_modules/.bin/metro-inspector-proxy
   ```

After these changes come back to the root of your project and do these commands:

1. yarn start --reset-cache
2. yarn ios

Then you can see everything works with the port number `9095`.

**NOTE:** for working with React Native Debugger just press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and change the port to `9095` and then you can connect your app to the React Native Debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using Visual Studio Code, just make sure you have declared the packager port correctly in your [launch.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations) file.
Then, restart your packager and try again.

```
...
"configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach to packager",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "type": "reactnative",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": "8081"
        }
    ] 
...
```