# package.json HTTPS=true causes "The command "HTTPS" is either misspelled or could not be found."

Tags: reactjs

I'm adding

```
HTTPS=true
```

to my package.json and starting my react frontend as always with "npm start" but it gives me

```
The command "HTTPS" is either misspelled or could not be found.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
```

**My package.json:**

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "SET HTTPS=true & SSL_CRT_FILE=domain.com.pem & SSL_KEY_FILE=domain.com-key.pem & cross-env HOST=domain.com react-scripts start",
```

I tried everything I found all over the place online but I destroyed more than I fixed an nothing seemed to work at the end. I'm on windows and tried different shells different formats with and without spaces, add "set " and "SET " at front and so on. Does anyone know why it seem to cannot find the HTTPS command?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["NODE\_ENV" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable command or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928013/node-env-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-comman)

Comment: I've tried "set" and "SET" already but its not starting anything after adding this. So it's sadly not fixing the error at all.

Comment: So *show that*, but trying the *nix way certainly isn't going to work.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you, so I added the full package.json line above so you can take a look at it.

Comment: Do you get the same error? Why haven't you used set with the other env vars?

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by using `cross-env` which allowed me to set my package.json to work on cross-platform as well. As this error came from trying to set HTTPS like on Linux based systems.

`cross-env` **documentation:** https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env

```
"start": "cross-env HTTPS=true SSL_CRT_FILE=domain.com.pem SSL_KEY_FILE=domain.com-key.pem HOST=domain.com react-scripts start"
```

Comment: That's also in the dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37131308/3001761