# 'npm run' angular script erroring unix commands on some computers but not others

Tags: node.js, angular, linux, npm

I'm having an issue at work that I can't seem to pinpoint the root cause. We have scripts we run via npm in angular to get a local instance of a server running. It seems like on some coworkers pcs the command errors. It seems to related to linux. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928013/node-env-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-comman). It is the same error but ANGULAR_ENV instead of NODE_ENV. Does anyone have any idea why it would work on some pcs but not others? Command is as follows `npm run-script dev:external`

Comment: Presumably because some of you are using e.g. git bash or other *nix-like command lines, and others are using a Windows shell. I'd suggest using `cross-env` or similar so that environment variables are handled consistently everywhere.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I thought that as well, but it didn't matter whether it was done in gitbash, visual studio terminal, or cmd. We had to run the following script config set script-shell "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this did it:

```
config set script-shell "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe"
```