# I can set 'NODE_ENV' on an npm script the linux way on one windows laptop, but not the other. I want to understand why

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, git-bash

I am just trying to understand the delta between the setup of my last windows laptop and my new one.

**Notes:**

- OLD runs windows 10, NEW runs windows 11.
- using git bash in both.
- WSL enabled in features in both (not sure if this matters at all).
- nvm controls node version in both.
- running an npm script defined as: `NODE_ENV=production gulp build`.
- no `cross-env`, `win-node-env` or similar packages installed on old one, globally or in the project.
- nothing in the windows PATH environment variable on either that would seem to affect this.

> OLD works fine, NEW gives the error: `'NODE_ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`.

Why would this happen on one and not the other? What else can I check? Happy to use cross-env and probably will, but I really just want to understand. Happy to provide any more details.

Comment: I don't think this is a WSL question, if you type help at the command prompt what do you get back, a version number like "GNU bash, version 5.2.15(1)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)" or an error?

Comment: @Damo No error, I get the help response: `GNU bash, version 5.2.15(1)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)`

Comment: @Damo Figured out the issue, See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I figured it out - **It turns out that `npm` was using `cmd` for its script shell, even though I am running the command in git bash**.

The fix is quite simple, set bash as the script shell and voila. No need for cross-env (or any other normalizer for that matter), and all of your developers can use the same scripts regardless of their OS.

**Set the npm script shell:**

```bash
npm config set shell "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"
npm config set script-shell "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"
```

**This will add entries to your `.npmrc` file as:**

```bash
script-shell=C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe
shell=C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe
```

May be a good idea to close and reopen your terminal.