# 'NODE_OPTIONS' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, build, vite

I have to build my react + vite project. When I'm writing `npm run build` I'm getting this error.

[image]

This is my `package.json` file

[image]

Comment: That's not how you set env vars on Windows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["NODE\_ENV" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable command or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928013/node-env-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-comman)

Comment: @jonrsharpe This was working fine before, deployed lots of changes in same project with same setup. idk why today I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the way you set the `NODE_OPTIONS` environment variable. What you have in your `package.json` works on Linux/Mac but not on Windows.

You can use `cross-env` ([npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env)) to handle env varibles on all major OS.

After installing the lib you can replace your `build` script with this:

```
"build": "tsc && cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=4906 vite build",
```