# Can Express.Js output minified JSON?

Tags: json, node.js, express, minify, restify

I'm currently switching from restified to Express, and I noticed that the output of res.send({}) in Express has pretty-printed JSON with white space, while the Restify output is minified without white space.

Since the JSON is not for human consumption, I prefer the minified output. Is there an easy way to get Express to output minified JSON without individually changing all the res.send() calls? I would also prefer a setting over adding more middle-ware for performance reasons.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can set the `json spaces` setting to 0:

```
var app = express();

app.set('json spaces', 0);
```

Express will do that automatically when you run it in production mode, though:

```
NODE_ENV=production node app
```

Comment: See here for instructions for windows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249830/how-can-i-set-node-env-production-in-windows

Comment: @Killroy oh yeah sorry, so used to Unix/Mac that I forgot about Windows :)