# Run mean stack app in production

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, cmd, gruntjs

I am just playing with MEAN stack but I can't figure out how to run my app in production mode to perform some benchmarking. Site mean.io says:

> To run with a different environment, just specify `NODE_ENV` as you call grunt:
>
> ```
> $ NODE_ENV=test grunt
> ```

How can I pass the variable to grunt?

Edit:
I am using Windows

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To decide if the application runs in production or development mode, it checks the `NODE_ENV` environment variable, which is a variable that you'll set in your shell and that will be read from node.

If you want to run `grunt` in production mode, use:

```sh
$ NODE_ENV=production grunt
```

which will set the variable **only for this execution**.

If you want to permanently set `NODE_ENV`, use `export`:

```sh
$ export NODE_ENV=production
$ grunt
```

On your production server, you can then edit `.bashrc` with this line to permanently set `NODE_ENV`.

For further information, you can read [this blog post](http://www.hacksparrow.com/running-express-js-in-production-mode.html).

*Edit:* On Windows, use `set NODE_ENV=production` on the command line. See [this relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9250168/2137601) to know how to permanently set this variable.

Comment: I see. I missed that it is the bash/shell command. I forgot to mention that I am using cmd.exe :)

Comment: Updated my answer for Windows then.

Comment: You shouldn't need sudo to set the `NODE_ENV` variable. However, if in production you use a restricted port (< 1024), then you will need root privileges to listen on this port. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573668/best-practices-when-running-node-js-with-port-80-ubuntu-linode) for instance.

Answer (score 0):

The following command works in my case:

```
grunt prod
```

Notice that I use `mean.js` version `0.4.2` and found this config in file `$HOME_PROJECT_FOLDER/gruntfile.js`