# Publish or deploy Nodejs project to build folder or FTP

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ftp, npm

I want to publish my nodeJS build folder or ftp
so in Cmd I write `npm run build` but it give that error 
In webpack or package.json I set Node_ENV to production

```
 18 error react-seed@0.0.13 build: `NODE_ENV=production npm run webpack`
    18 error Exit status 1
    19 error Failed at the react-seed@0.0.13 build script
   'NODE_ENV=production npm run webpack'.
    19 error This is most likely a problem with the react-seed package,
    19 error not with npm itself.
    19 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    19 error     NODE_ENV=production npm run webpack
```

How can I publish my project to any folder or ftp?

Comment: Are you building on windows by any chance? `NODE_ENV=production` isn't the correct syntax for windows.

Comment: @dvlsg yes on windows.It create folder like this $npm_package_config_buildDir  but it is empty.No file in that folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`react-seed` didn't make their `npm` scripts cross-platform compliant, as can be seen [here](https://github.com/badsyntax/react-seed/blob/f279eee9f0abc8ce23553832e1a3ebb6756feaa0/package.json#L14).

You could manually change the `package.json` in `react-seed` to be windows compliant, by editing the script build line to use this instead:

```
"build": "set NODE_ENV=production&& npm run webpack",
```

The missing space after `production` is intentional. Also note that this would make it not run on *nix environments, as it would be windows specific.

Honestly, it may be best to open a ticket with `react-seed` and let them know that their `npm` scripts are not cross-platform. Additional reading from stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249830/how-can-i-set-node-env-production-in-windows).