# Setting environment variables package.json in Windows 10

Tags: node.js

***UPDATE***: As it is explained in the question, this is not a duplicate because I have already tried adding the **set** keyword before the environment variable and that did not solve the problem.

---

I am in the process of learning node and typing examples from a book. The first examples deal with showing how the "http" module works and how to create a server to listen to requests. At some point the book asks to add the following line to the scripts section of the package.json file:

> "server": "SERVERPORT=3002 node ./fiboserver"

When I try to run the example with **npm run server** I get the following error message:

> 'SERVERPORT' is not recognized as an internal or external command

I haven't been able to find any answer on the internet, at most I found that I could try:

> "server": "set SERVERPORT=3002 node ./fiboserver"

But that doesn't help either, the only difference is that instead of the error message I get the command prompt again so apparently the server is never run.

I believe the author used a Linux machine, I am using a Windows 10 laptop.

I am really committed to learn Node and my line of work is on Windows environments. I believe that setting environment variables on package.json is important so I could really use some help in figuring this out.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you should separate the commands with the && sign. `set SERVERPORT=3002 && node ./fiboserver `

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i set NODE\_ENV=production in Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249830/how-can-i-set-node-env-production-in-windows)

Comment: @Ibrahim - Thank you. That worked. Could you add an answer so I can set it as the correct solution?

Comment: @Simon - Hi. I don't think this is a duplicate from the one you are proposing since the answer for that was only to use "set" before the variable and when I tried that it did not work.

Comment: @SergioRomero Hi, I disagree. If you look at the comments, the answer is given.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

On Windows you have to separate the command of setting a variable from the one which runs the server with the `&&` operator.
That being said, you have to do something like this:

`"server": "set SERVERPORT=3002 && node ./fiboserver"`

Comment: Wouldn't you end up with the value "3002 " (note the space)? That's the problem I was having, need to remove the space before &&.

Answer (score 57):

Make it cross-platform by using [`cross-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env):

```
"server": "cross-env SERVERPORT=3002 node ./fiboserver"
```

Answer (score 5):

I've gone through [the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60265153/5675325) and used one of the following methods.

---

### Method 1

If I run (without using the npm wrapper script)

```
HOST=0.0.0.0 PORT=8000 ./node_modules/.bin/react-scripts start
```

[image: Starting the development server...]

it works fine. As Quentin says,

> Must be something to do with how npm shells out then

To fix it, I've gone to package.json and changed the "start" script to

```
"start": "./node_modules/.bin/react-scripts start",
```

Then `npm start` works fine.

---

### Method 2

Use the [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) package.

For that install it using the following command

```
npm i cross-env
```

then go to package.json and change it to

```
"start": "cross-env ./node_modules/.bin/react-scripts start",
```

And then running `npm start` will also work fine:

[image: cross-env npm start]

Answer (score 3):

You can set bash as package.json scripts runner and it's will work in windows and linux.

Just set it once:

- for yarn `yarn config set script-shell /bin/bash`
- for npm `npm config set script-shell /bin/bash`

Or `"C:\\Program Files\\git\\bin\\bash.exe"` instead `/bin/bash`

It's will allow you to run npm script cross-platform:
`"server": "SERVERPORT=3002 node ./fiboserver"`