# HOST is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, reactjs

After cloning a Git repo with a ReactJS and NodeJS project and [install NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

[image: NodeJS installed]

wanted to see the result in the browser and for that had to run in the root folder which had a package.json

> npm install

and after

> npm start

First command worked fine but the second was giving the following error

```
> HOST=0.0.0.0 PORT=8000 ./node_modules/.bin/react-scripts start
'HOST' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ...: `HOST=0.0.0.0 PORT=8000 ./node_modules/.bin/react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ... start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

The package.json has the following

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "HOST=0.0.0.0 PORT=8000 ./node_modules/.bin/react-scripts start",
```

Tested using Git Bash, CMD and PowerShell and kept on getting the same error, as you can see in the following images

**Git Bash**

[image: Git Bash HOST is not recognized as an internal or external command]

**CMD**
[image: CMD HOST is not recognized as an internal or external command]

**PowerShell**
[image: PowerShell HOST is not recognized as an internal or external command]

Comment: I'd expect it to fail on cmd and maybe powershell, but that should work on bash AFAIK

Comment: @Quentin yea, i also thought it would work but it didn't...

Comment: @Quentin just added images to prove what I just said.

Comment: What happens if you run `HOST=0.0.0.0 PORT=8000 ./node_modules/.bin/react-scripts start` without using the `npm` wrapper script?

Comment: It opens as expected (using Git Bash)

Comment: Must be something to do with how `npm` shells out then

Comment: Found a duplicate. Use the `cross-env` package.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Method 1

If I run (without using the npm wrapper script)

```
HOST=0.0.0.0 PORT=8000 ./node_modules/.bin/react-scripts start
```

[image: Starting the development server...]

it works fine. As Quentin says,

> Must be something to do with how npm shells out then

To fix it, I've gone to package.json and changed the "start" script to

```
"start": "./node_modules/.bin/react-scripts start",
```

Then `npm start` works fine.

---

### Method 2

Use the [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) package.

For that install it using the following command

```
npm i cross-env
```

then go to package.json and change it to

```
"start": "cross-env ./node_modules/.bin/react-scripts start",
```

And then running `npm start` will also work fine:

[image: cross-env npm start]

Comment: Using cross-env works