# Why do I have to "SET SASS_PATH=.\node_modules" everytime I open my project on pycharm?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, sass, material-design

I have npm `6.12.0` and node `12.13.0`.

Every time I reopen the IDE and run my react app then I get the following error:

**error**

> ```
> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
> SassError: File to import not found or unreadable:
> @material/elevation/mixins. on line 23 of
> node_modules/@material/card/_mixins.scss from line 23 of
> node_modules/@material/card/mdc-card.scss from line 23 of
> node_modules/@material/react-card/index.scss from line 2 of
> /tmp/build_8663a9ab7ca425b4dba37090160b2ed2/assets/src/scss/index.scss
> @import "@material/elevation/mixins";
> ```

When I run:

```
SET SASS_PATH=.\node_modules
```

It goes away and the app works fine.

Why do I have to run this command again and again?

Comment: I believe you are using windows, so the issue is you have to set the system variable in your app package.json, or maybe system wide, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40806796/setting-environment-variables-package-json-in-windows-10