# Cannot read $ process.env.NODE_ENV using Windows

Tags: node.js, mongodb, process

I'm attempting to connect to a mlab db for production and my local db for development.  As far as I can tell my `NODE_ENV` is set to production.  But since I can't read it, I suspect that it's messed up somehow.  In addition, I keep connecting to my dev db.

I run my `mongod` instance.  And in another cli, navigate to my app folder, which houses my `app.js` file.  I'm following a tutorial which says to run

```
process.env.NODE_ENV
```

However, I get that this command is not recognized.  So I check my `NODE_ENV` variable using:  `set`
I get `NODE_ENV=production`, which I had previously set.  However.  When I run my app using `npm start` I still connect to my dev server.  Here is my `db.js code`:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var gracefulShutdown;
var dbURI = 'mongodb://localhost/Loc8r';

if(process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production'){
console.log('we are in production');
    dbURI = 'mongodb://username:password@ds55555.mlab.com:55555/dbname'
}
mongoose.connect(dbURI);


// to address mongoose closing issues in windows
var readLine = require('readline');
if (process.platform === "win32"){
    var rl = readLine.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout
    });
    rl.on ("SIGINT", function(){
        process.emit ("SIGINT");
    });
}
// close Mongoose connection, passing in an anonymous function to run when closed
gracefulShutdown = function(msg, callback){
    mongoose.connection.close(function(){
        console.log("Mongoose disconnected through " + msg);
        callback();
    });
};

mongoose.connection.on('connected', function(){
    console.log('Mongoose connected to ' + dbURI);
});

mongoose.connection.on('error', function(err){
    console.log('Mongoose connection error: ' + err);
});

mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function(){
    console.log('Mongoose disconnected');
});

// for nodemon termination
process.once('SIGUSR2', function(){
    gracefulShutdown('nodemon restart', function(){
        process.kill(process.pid, 'SIGUSR2');
    });
});

// for app termination
process.on('SIGINT', function(){
    gracefulShutdown('app termination', function(){
        process.exit(0);
    });
});

// for HEroku termination
process.on('SIGTERM', function(){
    gracefulShutdown('Heroku app shutdown', function(){
        process.exit(0);
    });
});

require('./locations');
```

Not sure where to start looking. I've exhausted my google searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found the answer in a clause in this comment 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9250168/5574017
Apparently, in Windows, `set NODE_ENV=production` should be executed in the directory where you house `app.js`

Still I cannot read my `$ process.env.NODE_ENV`

but I can read it with `set` and then searching for `NODE_ENV`

Sorry if I wasted your time.

Thanks, guys.