# ExpressJs doesn't cache views in production mode

Tags: node.js, express, caching, production-environment, viewengine

I have a problem with `ExpressJs` not caching my `views` when `NODE_ENV` is set to `production`. I'm using the `EJS template engine`. Here is my code:

*npm script*

```
"start": "set NODE_ENV=production && node ./bin/www"
```

*app.js*

```
console.log(app.get('env')) => logs production
console.log(app.get('view cache')) => logs undefined
app.set('view cache', true)
console.log(app.get('view cache')) => logs true
```

So it seems that when I set the `NODE_ENV` environment variable to `production` `ExpressJs` is not enabling view cache, but when I enable it manually by calling `app.set('view cache', true)` it will. According to the [`ExpressJs`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.render) it should enable view caching by default.

I did test if the caching works, but it only does when I enable it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem is not with `ExpressJs` or with `npm scripts`, but with the shell command I used.

When using a `console.dir` I saw that `NODE_ENV` was set to `production` with an extra space. Changing the npm script to `"start": "set NODE_ENV=production&&node ./bin/www"` did work.

Answer (score 0):

First run your app by `NODE_ENV=production node app.js` and if its `true` so you should change your `start` attribute in `package.json`.

Comment: Did you mean running `set NODE_ENV=production && node ./bin/www` from the CLI? I did that but unfortunately with the same result. I'm on Windows, so the code you provided will not work..

Comment: When you run from CLI you don't need 'set' and '&'.

Comment: A error is thrown when I don't use them: `'NODE_ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
`

Comment: Did you see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249830/how-can-i-set-node-env-production-in-windows

Comment: Now I have. As you can read there I have to use 'set' and '&&' on Windows, but without spaces. I'm not on unix. I don't get it that node is not trimming the value of the variable to avoid this. Also I know that it isn't a good idea to set an environment variable hardcoded in package.json, I only wanted to test production.

`npm run env NODE_ENV=production` did not work at all for me..