# How I can pass opts/flags which I pass to npm install command to postinstall scripts?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts

How I can pass opts/flags which I pass to npm install command to postinstall scripts?

I write `npm install X --some-param=some-value` command. `X` package has `postinstall` script: `./scripts/postinstall.js`. How I can pass some-param to postinstall script?

I try `process.argv` but it does not contain anything which I use as `npm install` params.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to do that, since `npm install` assumes all arguments it doesn't recognize are package names. What works, and is a common solution, is to use environment variables instead. When you do this:

```
$ SOME_PARAM=some-value npm install
```

...you can then access the value of `SOME_PARAM` with `process.env.SOME_PARAM` in your `postinstall.js` script.

Comment: Hm. Yes this will work on MacOS or maybe in linux. IT is not as easy in Windows. Any cross-os solution? Thougts?

Comment: See this related question, which has several viable answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249830/how-can-i-set-node-env-production-in-windows

Answer (score 0):

You can access the args with `process.env.npm_config_argv`.

Running `yarn install --test-arg` will give a value of `{"remain":[],"cooked":["install"],"original":["install","--test-arg"]}`.

Comment: Does not work in npm v10.2.4 & node v20.11.0. `process.env.npm_config_argv` is undefined.