# Why are values set with setx not passed to Node's process.env?

Tags: node.js, powershell

```
$ setx NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED 0

SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.

$ node -e "console.log(process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED); console.dir(process.env.windir);"
undefined
'C:\\WINDOWS'
```

`setx` said it worked (value was "saved"). But the node process.env object doesn't contain it. Why is `setx` wrong?

This didn't work either:

```
$ set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
$ node -e "console.log(process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED)"
undefined
```

Incidentally it did work with this command: `$env:NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED="0"`

Related: [How can I set NODE_ENV=production on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249830/how-can-i-set-node-env-production-on-windows).

Comment: Are you starting a new instance of node after setting the variable? (Environment variables on Windows are generally inherited rather than propagated.)

Comment: To change the current environment ( not the master/persistent environment) simply use `$ENV:NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0`

Comment: @LotPings that's in my post already

Comment: @Bill_Stewart that's what `node -e` does, evaluates code in a new node instance

Comment: I don't know the details, but if it's not working, perhaps "new instance" != "new process". Environment variables are tied to processes.

Comment: But the new instance inherits it's emvironment from the current process.

Comment: Correct, so setting the variable in the current process should be all that's needed.