# What is the error when I set "NODE_ENV=production", how to set environment variable for node script command?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, production-environment

I use webpack 3.1.0, node 9.2.0, command line of windows 10.

Got the error when I run script on package.json.

```
"scripts": {
"build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --colors -p",
...
}
```

I get the errors like below.

```
13 verbose stack Error: wow_dns@1.0.0 build: `NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --colors -p`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sheng\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:285:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:159:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sheng\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:159:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:943:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5)
14 verbose pkgid wow_dns@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd F:\wow\wow_dns
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.16299
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\sheng\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
```

But it would be run through, if I delete "NODE_ENV=production" like:

```
"scripts": {
"build": "webpack --progress --colors -p",
...
}
```

It will works.
How to setting running environment in with production environment?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set NODE\_ENV=production on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249830/how-can-i-set-node-env-production-on-windows)

Comment: No that one is on windows shell setting. For me I want put in package.json with one line command.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please change

```
"build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --colors -p"
```

to

```
"build": "set NODE_ENV=production;webpack --progress --colors -p"
```

or

```
"build": "NODE_ENV=production;webpack --progress --colors -p"
```

The problem is that once you finish a command you need to give a semicolon to say that command is over.

Comment: Setting an environment variable is not the same as running a command. If you use `export` then it would become a command but the other case isn't correct.

Comment: `"build": "NODE_ENV=production && webpack --progress --colors -p"`

Answer (score 2):

In windows, use `&` to connect two commands, eg:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "serve": "SET NODE_ENV=development& webpack serve --progress --color",
  "build": "SET NODE_ENV=production& webpack --progress --color",
  "serve-old": "webpack-dev-server --watch"
},
```