# NODE_ENV with Jest

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js, jestjs

I am migrating from Mocha to Jest. My test imports the `config` package, which selects a configuration file or another depending on the `NODE_ENV` environment variable. However, it looks like `NODE_ENV` is found while running the test from Jest

Next line does not work (that is, `NODE_ENV` is ignored):

```
 NODE_ENV=test jest test/*.js --notify --config jest.config.json
```

As a consequence the `config` package reports:

```
console.error node_modules/config/lib/config.js:1727
WARNING: NODE_ENV value of 'test' did not match any deployment config file names.
```

Do you know how to include `NODE_ENV`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Jest automatically defines environment variable `NODE_ENV` as `test`(see https://jestjs.io/docs/environment-variables), as you can confirm from your error message:

```
console.error node_modules/config/lib/config.js:1727
WARNING: NODE_ENV value of 'test' did not match any deployment config file names.
```

What you can do is simply create config/test.json and include the contents `{}`, which is an empty valid JSON object.

See https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Strict-Mode

**Note**: the aforementioned error occurs when you use the [config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config) package, and meanwhile you don't have the test.json file in the config directory.

Comment: How to override the NODE_ENV defined by jest? Can i assign that NODE_ENV with my own environment?

Comment: @dennbagas, yes, you can. For example, on Mac/Linux, you can try `$ NODE_ENV=dev npm run test`, and `NODE_ENV` will be set to `dev`; on Windows, check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249830/how-can-i-set-node-env-production-on-windows

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is using [`cross-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) package:

```
npm install --save-dev cross-env
```

Then, you can use it in your `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development jest --config jest.config.json"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The warning is from the Strict-Mode. So what you have to do here is..

1. Create a file called `test.json` inside `config/`
2. Add `NODE_ENV` value as `test`

That should work

Answer (score 0):

Please create `test.js` in the config folder:

```
module.exports = {};
```

and then add `dotenv-cli` as devDependencies

```
dotenv -e .env -- jest --maxWorkers=50% --watch
```

Note: [jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/environment-variables) automatically set **NODE_ENV=test**