# how to configure webpack2?

Tags: reactjs, webpack-2

I added this variable in my package:

```
json file : "prod": "npm run clean && NODE_ENV=production  webpack -p"
```

finally i had this error:

> 'NODE_ENV' n’est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.

Comment: You may want to display the error message in English. More people will be able to understand it to help you and it may be a recognizable common error a lot of people have.

Comment: Are you using windows? The commands in your package.json will be executed by your shell. This command will work in bash, but probably not in windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set NODE\_ENV=production on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249830/how-can-i-set-node-env-production-on-windows)

Comment: ok  this the error  message: 
'NODE_ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command, an executable program, or a batch file.

Comment: i added SET  in the console i haven"t errors  but nothing happens in my  dist  folder files  wasn't reloaded

Comment: my package.json:  "scripts": {
    "dev": " webpack-dev-server",
  
    "prod": "npm run clean &&  NODE_ENV=production webpack -p",
    "clean": "rimraf ./dist/*"
  },

Comment: my webpack config file:var isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'; // true or false
var cssDev = ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'];
var cssProd = ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    fallbackLoader: 'style-loader' ,
    loader: ['css-loader','sass-loader'],
    publicPath: '/dist'
  } )