# How can I correctly set the local currency when testing with Jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, internationalization, jestjs

When testing an [IntL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) money conversion inside Jest, I don't get the correct conversion.

**My test:**

```js
expect(new Intl.NumberFormat('pt-BR', { style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' }).format(50.00)).toBe('R$ 50,00');
// Expected value to be:
// "R$ 50,00"
// Received:
// "R$ 50.00"
```

**My command:**

```
jest --config test/unit/jest.conf.js
```

How can I set the correct locale configuration to Jest?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Full ICU now comes with Node.js, [since version 13](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v13.x/api/intl.html).

---

**Original answer:**

The challenge here is to set Node.js i18n, Jest is Node.js based.

Accordingly, with [official Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/intl.html#intl_providing_icu_data_at_runtime), we must set the full-icu parameter.

```
npm install full-icu
NODE_ICU_DATA=node_modules/full-icu jest --config jest.conf.js
```

Now the test is correct.

Comment: is there any way to do this inside of the jest setup files?

Comment: @KellyMilligan I don't see how it's possible. Here we got an explicit argument about ICU, before Node.js loading. Inside Jest configuration, you are declaring something to be loaded after Node.js...

Comment: @JasonRice good question. You need to find some way to dynamically set the `NODE_ICU_DATA` before executing jest. Maybe that link can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249830/how-can-i-set-node-env-production-on-windows.

Comment: I ended up using cross-env from NPM and then set the following for our stage and production server: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production node --icu-data-dir=node_modules/full-icu -r esm src/server/index.js` This works really well. Then within your local dev environment simply add the following to your .env: `NODE_ICU_DATA=node_modules/full-icu`

Answer (score 0):

Probably in Brazil use comma sign`,` to separate decimal numbers. Instead of dot sign `.`.
Here is the link to world map which indicates which country, uses which decimal indicator.
http://www.statisticalconsultants.co.nz/blog/how-the-world-separates-its-decimals.html

Comment: Thanks! I've considered a String replacement. I will look for a more precise approach.