# Getting issues while installing React Project on Windows system

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I am trying to install a React Web Application on my Windows system. It was working fine earlier but when I re-installed my Windows then it stopped working. I have already installed Node and Npm.

When I run the command `npm install` it goes well. But when I run the command `npm start` it throws the following error:

> REACT_APP_ENV is not recognized as an internal or external command

Please see the attached image also:

[image]

I have tried a lot to find and fix the issue but nothing worked.

Here is package.json file content:

```
{
  "name": "wm-webapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "gapi-client": "0.0.3",
    "libphonenumber-js": "^1.7.7",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.4",
    "react-dates": "^18.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-facebook-login": "^4.1.1",
    "react-google-login": "^5.0.0",
    "react-places-autocomplete": "^7.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-responsive": "^6.1.1",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.9",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.3",
    "react-select": "^1.2.1",
    "react-stripe-elements": "^2.0.2",
    "react-table": "^6.8.6",
    "react-toastify": "^4.5.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.7",
    "redux-form": "^8.1.0",
    "redux-form-input-masks": "^1.3.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-saga": "^1.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "store": "^2.0.12",
    "styled-components": "^4.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start:env": "env-cmd .env.${REACT_APP_ENV} react-scripts start",
    "start": "REACT_APP_ENV=dev npm run start:env",
    "start:test": "REACT_APP_ENV=test npm run start:env",
    "build:env": "env-cmd .env.${REACT_APP_ENV} react-scripts build",
    "build": "REACT_APP_ENV=test npm run build:env",
    "build:prod": "REACT_APP_ENV=prod npm run build:env",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "deploy": "aws s3 cp build s3://test.washmix.com/ --recursive --profile washmix",
    "format": "prettier --write --single-quote --tab-width=2 --print-width=80"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.16.0",
    "env-cmd": "^8.0.2",
    "husky": "^1.3.1",
    "prettier": "^1.16.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share you package.json file as well?

Comment: is this a create-react-app ?

Comment: Try running set `REACT_APP_ENV=dev` in the command prompt before running `npm start`.

Comment: seems like a duplicate issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249830/how-can-i-set-node-env-production-on-windows

Comment: @AkashdeepSingh tired, still showing same error

Comment: @lomse code added, please check

Comment: @DhavalChheda No, I got that app from my client. I am trying to set up on my Windows system

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249830/how-can-i-set-node-env-production-on-windows should fix your issue. How are you doing it?

Comment: @lomse it doesn't help

Comment: Use `create-react-app`!

Answer (score 10):

Already late to answer but for people searching for the answer..

**For Windows (cmd.exe) :**

```
'set "REACT_APP_ENV=dev" && npm run start'
```

**For Windows (Powershell) :**

```
'($env:REACT_APP_ENV = "dev") -and (npm start)'
```

**For Linux, macOS (Bash) :**

```
'REACT_APP_ENV=dev npm start'
```

You can anytime get thing variable with **process.env.REACT_APP_ENV**

Answer (score 8):

You must change all environment variables in your package.json for:

```
Set NAME_VARIABLE=VALUE
```

Ex:

```
"start": "Set REACT_APP_ENV=dev&& npm run start:env",
```

Comment: this solution finally worked for me! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're running on windows, remember to leave no space between the commands and &&.
So the start script will be :

`"start-staging":"set REACT_APP_ENV=staging&&react-scripts start"`

Comment: Not necessary with the tests I ran through. e.g. `"build:qa": "Set REACT_APP_ENV=qa && npm run build"`

Answer (score 0):

In script-> start, write cross-env in starting of the value.
After that
Run: npm install.

And you are ready to go