# When i run the npm run build for react project i am getting the error, please check below code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, windows

```
'REACT_APP_BUILD_ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! argon-dashboard-pro-react@1.2.0 build: `react-csp dev && REACT_APP_BUILD_ENV='test' react-scripts build && gulp licenses`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the argon-dashboard-pro-react@1.2.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Shubham Jayswal\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-03-22T13_44_53_411Z-debug.log
```

I am trying to build my code but when I run npm run build with react project getting every time error, stuck there don't have an idea how to resolve that error, could please give me solution how to fix that error.

I am using Windows.

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/a/60925376/8705343

Comment: `REACT_APP_BUILD_ENV='test'` This section of the command will not work on Windows.


Install the `cross-env` npm package: `npm install --save-dev cross-env`

Change that part of the command to `cross-env REACT_APP_BUILD_ENV='test'`

Answer (score 0):

if on windows
change build in package.json to
react-csp dev && set REACT_APP_BUILD_ENV='test' react-scripts build && gulp licenses

Comment: Yes already added that please check it:                                                                              
"build": "REACT_APP_BUILD_ENV='test' react-scripts build && gulp licenses"

Comment: You are missing the word 'set' @subhamindapoint

Comment: I have added: "build": "set REACT_APP_BUILD_ENV='test' react-scripts build && gulp licenses", Getting another error.

Comment: $ npm run build

> argon-dashboard-pro-react@1.2.0 build C:\Users\Shubham Jayswal\Desktop\admin-panel
> set REACT_APP_BUILD_ENV='test' react-scripts build && gulp licenses

[19:39:59] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\admin-panel\gulpfile.js
[19:39:59] Starting 'licenses'...
[19:39:59] Finished 'licenses' after 15 ms
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: File not found with singular glob: C:/Users/Shubham Jayswal/Desktop/admin-panel/build/index.html (if this was purposeful, use `allowEmpty` option)
    at Glob.<anonymous>........