# Passing NODE_ENV into the npm script for Windows 10

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, environment-variables, npm-scripts

I am using `webpack` in a Typescript project. I am following a [tutorial](https://medium.com/free-code-camp/build-an-apollo-graphql-server-with-typescript-and-webpack-hot-module-replacement-hmr-3c339d05184f) where I have created 3 `webpack` files:

1. `webpack.common.js`
2. `webpack.production.js`
3. `webpack.development.js`

Within the tutorial's `package.json` the `"scripts"` seconds have the following:

```
"build": "webpack --config webpack.$NODE_ENV.js"
```

I have been looking into the [following SE Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249830/how-can-i-set-node-env-production-on-windows) to set the `NODE_ENV` for Windows 10.

Where within PowerShell I perform:

```
$env:NODE_ENV="development"
```

However once I execute `npm run build` the script still takes `$NODE_ENV` as a string and does not substitute the values.

I might shift to `cross-env` later if this doesn't work for me but I would like to give environments variables a try in the PowerShell.

What should be the equivalent commands for:

```
NODE_ENV=development npm run build
NODE_ENV=production npm run build
```

in windows and how should I change the `scripts` in my `package.json` viz. `$NODE_ENV` to accept the variables?

#### Using `cross-env`

It is possible to achieve something similar using `cross-env` by doing the following:

1. `npm i --save-dev cross-env`
2. Within `"scripts"` add:

   ```
    "build-dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack --config webpack.%NODE_ENV%.js"
    "build-prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.%NODE_ENV%.js"
   ```

   And this should trigger the respective scripts.

however, this still does not provide flexibility for user to run a generic npm script command whilst setting the env. variable *on the fly*

#### PowerShell Limitations

There are examples where queries suggest doing something of the likes of:

```
  set NODE_ENV=production&& npm run build
```

but this fails in PowerShell with the following error:

```sh
At line:1 char:24
+ set NODE_ENV=production&& npm run build-dev
+                        ~~
The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidEndOfLine
```

And `&` is reserved for future-use.

Comment: You could have 3 separate build commands like: `build-common` `build-dev` and `build-prod` and set env there itself, example: `"build-dev": "set NODE_ENV=production&&webpack --config webpack.development.js"`

Comment: @ambianBeing but doesn't this defeat the purpose of selecting the file based on environment variable set?

Comment: I know that's not exactly what you asked. But that's a cleaner way to do it. Otherwise I would've suggested write conditional statements in the `build` script but that's not pretty. Changing webpack config can achieve that as well I think but why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to Solve this issue based on comment from @ambienBeing. However here are some Caveats:

- The `&&` **DOES NOT** work in the `PowerShell` but **WORKS** in `cmd`
- Instead of `$NODE_ENV` I needed to adapted `%NODE_ENV%` in the `"scripts"` part

  ```
  "build": "echo %NODE_ENV% && webpack --config webpack.%NODE_ENV%.js"
  ```

Upon executing the following:

```
 set NODE_ENV=production&&npm run build
```

the script gets executed correctly.

In order to be sure, I added `console.log("production")` as well as `console.log("development")` in the respective `webpack.x.js` files

and I could see the respective string printed in the console twice: 1 x from `echo` and 1 x from the file

### Tests

- This works perfectly well with VS Code when one changes the default shell to `cmd` instead of `PowerShell`

Answer (score 1):

Change your package.json like the below:

Note you have to change all webpack.common.js, webpack.production.js, webpack.development.js

```
 webpack.common.js:

"build": "set NODE_ENV=development && webpack --config webpack.common.js"


 webpack.production.js:

"build": "set NODE_ENV=production && webpack --config webpack.production.js"


 webpack.development.js:

"build": "set NODE_ENV=development && webpack --config webpack.development.js"
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It still takes the `$NODE_ENV` as a string and does not substitute it

Comment: Edited the answer please check. You will have to do that change in three different files

Comment: I am not accessing them at the moment. I am just trying to use the Webpack HMR (Hot Module Reload) to work for a simple hello world

Comment: If you change all the three webpack configs it should work

Comment: In this case how will I know which environment will be set if the script is all named `build`?

Comment: In you rpackage.json -> scripts - "build": "set NODE_ENV=production && your_build_command" - by this way when you run "npm run build" it will pick up the correct environment. This is how its normally done