# snack-web from expo is not working locally

Tags: react-native, expo

I have cloned the repo for [snack-web](https://github.com/expo/snack-web) locally.
Followed the instructions as mentioned in the Readme.
But getting below issue:

```
$ if-env NODE_ENV=production && yarn start:prod || yarn start:dev
$ yarn domain
$ hotel start && hotel add http://localhost:3011 --name snack.expo
Started http://localhost:2000
Create ~\.hotel\servers\snack.expo.json
$ nodemon -e json,js,ts,tsx --watch src/server src/server/index.tsx --exec babel-node --extensions '.ts,.tsx'
[nodemon] 1.19.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching dir(s): src\server\**\*
[nodemon] watching extensions: json,js,ts,tsx
[nodemon] starting `babel-node src/server/index.tsx --extensions '.ts,.tsx'`
D:\projects\snack-web\src\server\index.tsx:3
import path from 'path';
       ^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\projects\snack-web\node_modules\@babel\node\lib\_babel-node.js:174:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

[Issue](https://github.com/expo/snack-web/issues/13) is already opened in github, but no reply.
Does anyone here on SO help me resolve this issue? Or help understand what is the real cause? Any workarounds?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think because of single quote in start:dev command. cmd does't support single quote.
try change package.json line 9 to this
"start:dev": "nodemon -e json,js,ts,tsx --watch src/server src/server/index.tsx --exec babel-node --extensions \".ts,.tsx\"",

Comment: Did that but a new error is coming now. `D:\projects\snack\snack-web\node_modules\nullthrows\nullthrows.js:9
  throw error;
  ^

Error: Got unexpected undefined
    at nullthrows (D:\projects\snack\snack-web\node_modules\nullthrows\nullthrows.js:7:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\projects\snack\snack-web\src\server/EmbeddedSnackScript.tsx:6:14)`

Comment: That error most probably because you haven't yet set the environment variables

Make sure you have the environment variables available:

export SNACK_PORT=3011
export SNACK_SEGMENT_KEY=""
export SNACK_SENTRY_DSN=""
export SNACK_SERVER_HOST=snack.expo.test
export SNACK_SERVER_PROTOCOL=https
export API_SERVER_URL=https://staging.expo.io
export IMPORT_SERVER_URL=https://staging.snackager.expo.io

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks. But now it says invalid DSN, do I need KEY and DSN values and do you know the same?

Comment: Finally, it is working. Thanks to you. Also, tip for someone who want to work on windows powershell. variables don't work as expected. For you need to use "FALSE" and for DSN - you might need to edit config file. sometimes single quotes are useful. Very weird behaviour.

Comment: What exactly did you do to fix the problem

Comment: @rahoolm pls help

Comment: @ClaretNnamocha have you tried this https://github.com/expo/snack-web/issues/13#issuecomment-564481209

Comment: The question I have is where to put the single quotes @Saf

Comment: @ClaretNnamocha see answers on this question on how to set environment variables on windows https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249830/how-can-i-set-node-env-production-on-windows

Comment: I have tried that but it goes back to being undefined. Please if you have a working version could you publish it on GitHub so I could check it out @Saf

Comment: @ClaretNnamocha try restarting your computer.

Comment: Just restarted, it didn't make a difference @Saf

Comment: Sorry @ClaretNnamocha haven't check it since many days. set it to false. $env:SNACK_SENTRY_DSN=''FALSE", you can directly modify a file in node_modules where the code is written. Lets continue on github.