# Configuration instructions are not clear

Tags: javascript, node.js, config

Here is what they say about the configuration:

```
Make sure you have run npm install
Build the dist directory by running BUILD_MODE=dist npm run build
Establish a link to this repository by running npm link
```

No problem concerning nodejs installation or linking, but the line "running BUILD_MODE=dist npm run build", I don't know how to run that, it's not a valid command... Maybe I'm just dumb, but if you can explain to me how to do that, I'd appreciate it.

Oh and I'm on Windows 10

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Like: copy&paste that line into the shell?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249830/how-can-i-set-node-env-production-on-windows

Comment: copy paste it send an error, but run "set  BUILD_MODE=dist npm run build" does not send an error, but it does nothing. And if i run npm run build after, the dist directory is still empty

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, you will need to run below commands.

```
set BUILD_MODE=dist
npm run build
npm link
```