# Set env in windows command line/ package.json

Tags: javascript, reactjs, windows, npm

Am having issues running a `react` app on `windows`.

The app was initially setup to run on a `macOS`.
Below are the error messages and `package.json` file.

**Question**:
How can I start and build `PORT` for windows?

package.json

```sh
{
  "name": "tradingview-finnhub",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "PORT=8080 react-scripts start",
    "build": "PORT=8080 react-scripts build"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Error message

```sh
'PORT' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! tradingview-finnhub@ start: `PORT=8080 react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

Comment: Use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I set NODE\_ENV=production on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249830/how-can-i-set-node-env-production-on-windows)

Comment: Simply remove the part `PORT=8080` from those scripts, that should work (at least, if it was set up with `create-react-app`). Once it runs, then you could get back and declare `PORT=3000`. Starting with either approach should give us insight...

Comment: This worked perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `set` before the PORT=8080 and a `&` after it.

It would be something like:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "set PORT=8080 & react-scripts start",
    "build": "set PORT=8080 & react-scripts build"
  },
```

The problem is that you need to set the environment variable of PORT before running the react-script, the solution I gave does that. For more info you can see:

https://superuser.com/questions/79612/setting-and-getting-windows-environment-variables-from-the-command-prompt

[How do I run two commands in one line in Windows CMD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055371/how-do-i-run-two-commands-in-one-line-in-windows-cmd)

Comment: Worked like a charm, I was also able to get it to work by removing `PORT=8080` all together and just running `react-script-build`. Thank you for the info!