# How to set the NODE_ENV with npm script on windows?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to understand how to be able to set the NODE_ENV variable during my start script in node.  I am using a windows machine and I have seen some answers about this for mac/linux but I cannot figure it out on windows (disclaimer: I am new to windows shell scripting).

Currently I have this:

```
"scripts": {
    "serve_dev": "set NODE_ENV=development && nodemon index.js",
},
```

Which does not work.  I have also tried adding $env:NODE_ENV... and that did not work as well.  Does someone know how I can do this?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249830/how-can-i-set-node-env-production-on-windows this might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue and it was due to the spaces.  The correct implimentation is:

```
"scripts": {
    "serve_dev": "set NODE_ENV=development&&nodemon index.js",
},
```