# I can't set my flask environment to development. It stays in production

Tags: python-3.x, windows, flask

I can't set my flask environment to development. It stays in production.

```
PS C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\webserver> Scripts\Activate.ps1
(webserver) PS C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\webserver> $env:FLASK_APP = "server.py"
(webserver) PS C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\webserver> set FLASK_ENV=development
(webserver) PS C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\webserver> flask run
* Serving Flask app 'server.py' (lazy loading)
* Environment: production
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
Use a production WSGI server instead.
* Debug mode: off`enter code here`
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Comment: You do the right thing for `FLASK_APP` in PowerShell: `$env:FLASK_APP = "server.py"`. Then you do the _wrong_ thing by using the cmd syntax: `set FLASK_ENV=development`. Why are you changing?

Comment: I disagree with the selected duplicate. The issue here is about setting environment variables in PowerShell. Here's a better one: [How can I set NODE_ENV=production on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9249830/354577)

Answer (score 0):

As described in [Flask - Quickstart](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#debug-mode), if you want to enable the debug mode (development) with **PowerShell**, you need to do:

```
> $env:FLASK_APP = "server.py"
> $env:FLASK_ENV = "development"
> flask run
```

`set` will not be recognized by **PowerShell**, but **CMD** will.