# 'URL' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, npm, nestjs

Windows 10 and Node version 16.13.1

I have a custom script in my package.json.When i trying to install npm packages,it's giving be bellow error;

> > URL=http://172.xxx.xx/repository/npm-registry
>
> 'URL' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
> program or batch file. npm ERR! code 1

Package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "node index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest --config=jest.json",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch --config=jest.json",
    "test:coverage": "jest --config=jest.json --coverage --coverageDirectory=coverage",
    "preinstall": "URL=http://172.xxx.xx./repository/npm-registry"
  },
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I set NODE\_ENV=production on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249830/how-can-i-set-node-env-production-on-windows)

Comment: Highly recommend [env-cmd](https://github.com/toddbluhm/env-cmd)

Comment: `npm config set registry http://172.xxx.xx./repository/npm-registry`  or create `.npmrc` with content: `registry=http://172.xxx.xx./repository/npm-registry`  also if You want to set env vars use `.env` file format and use `dotenv` package in app to read that file contents, `env-cmd` package is also deal, depending on Your favour.

Answer (score 1):

Add `set` before the `preinstall` script. like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "node index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest --config=jest.json",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch --config=jest.json",
    "test:coverage": "jest --config=jest.json --coverage --coverageDirectory=coverage",
    "preinstall": "set URL=http://172.xxx.xx./repository/npm-registry"
  },
```