# Node.js environment detection not working Heroku

Tags: node.js

I've been working on a Node.js project for several months and for some reason the logic I have set up stopped working. I'm not sure where to begin debugging the issue. My workaround has been to comment out the development lines when pushing to production.

```
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

if(env === 'development'){
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mean-demo');
  }else{
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:password@ds043270.mongolab.com:ds043270/location');
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're firing up your node process with specifying the NODE_ENV the same as you used to?. i.e. are you calling `$ NODE_ENV=prod node index.js` or something along those lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first line should be `var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';`, although I guess that shouldn't really matter... but if you're going to use `env` anyway, not sure why you need to set process.env.NODE_ENV.

Also, make sure your environment is not accidentally already set using directions in this post: [process.env.NODE_ENV is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11104028/process-env-node-env-is-undefined) to set it to `development`

But other than that you may find a module like [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) helpful. Basically you make a `.env` file that has properties like Mongo URL details and it does NOT get committed to source control. You keep one `.env` in each environment.

Comment: That did it thanks! After running <heroku config:set NODE_ENV=production> it worked

Comment: Good code correction. However, the method of not checking .env files into source control wouldn't work on Heroku, as far as I know, because the usual workflow for getting files into Heroku involves checking them in and pushing them up to Heroku.