# set NODE_ENV on DigitalOcean Ubuntu server

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-16.04, production-environment, package.json, npm-scripts

I have a Node.js application.
My build script in my package.json looks like this:

```
"build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js && set NODE_ENV=production&& npm run express-server"
```

When I run this script locally on my computer, I can access the process.env.NODE_ENV and it sure enough is in "production"

But when I do the same thing on my Ubuntu server hosted on digital ocean, then process.env.NODE_ENV is 'undefined'.

How can I set the NODE_ENV in a npm script on a Ubuntu server?

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

3. According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11104028/process-env-node-env-is-undefined#answer-21786284) it says:

   > In UBUNTU use:
   >
   > `$ export NODE_ENV=test`

   Note, the use of `export` instead of `set`.

---

**Original answer:**

1. Firstly try changing your `build` script to:

   ```
   "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js && NODE_ENV=\"production\" npm run express-server"
   ```

   Note the `set` keyword has been omitted, escaped double quotes have been wrapped around `\"production\"`, and the `&&` operator has been removed.
2. If that also fails then checkout [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env). It's documentation states:

   > Most Windows command prompts will choke when you set environment variables with `NODE_ENV=production` like that. (The exception is Bash on Windows, which uses native Bash.) Similarly, there's a difference in how windows and POSIX commands utilize environment variables. With POSIX, you use: `$ENV_VAR` and on windows you use `%ENV_VAR%`.

   So perhaps try utilizing `cross-env` and change your `build` script to the following:

   ```
   "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js && cross-env NODE_ENV=\"production\" npm run express-server"
   ```