# How do I get my deployed React.js app to use API secret keys? I'm using Heroku confing vars but still not working

Tags: node.js, heroku, oauth, github-api, api-key

**Problem:**

I created a simple React app (using Javascript and Node) that uses the GitHub API to search for users and return information about them. I need to use a GitHub oauth key so that I can make authenticated API requests. However, I am having trouble giving my deployed app (using Heroku) the key without hard-coding it into the API call. I'm fairly new at this so any help would be great! I linked the github repo at the bottom of this post.

I have tried several things which I will explain below:

**Attempt 1:**

1. I created a file where I set my GitHub key to a variable and exported it ([Image of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ixqu.png))
2. I put said file in the .gitignore
3. I imported the variable in the files where I made API calls and used them it directly in the API call. ([Image of API call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpQ2Q.png))
4. This worked on my dev environment but (obviously) did not work on my deployed Heroku app because it had no idea what the variable was. ([Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pw9Gw.png))

**Attempt 2:**

1. I configured variables in Heroku and set GITHUB_KEY to my key. ([Image of Heroku variable setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwHIl.png)).
2. Next, I checked that Heroku recognized this variable by running the command `heroku config:get GITHUB_KEY` and received the correct key in response ([Image of terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynO35.png))
3. In my secrets file, I set the variable like so: `process.env.GITHUB_KEY = 'a93b2c21918b42df5a28e0e529c627ee22c60de4';` ([Image of setting variable using process.env](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Y0qt.png))
4. And then I use it in my API calls on the frontend: `const res = await fetch(
     'https://api.github.com/users/${this.state.input}?access_token=${process.env.GITHUB_KEY}'
   );`. 
   However, I get the following error: `SearchBar.js:32 GET https://api.github.com/users/livmarx?access_token=undefined 401 (Unauthorized)`. ([Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgIbT.png)).

So, I know that I'm misunderstanding how process.env works but cannot seem to figure it out! Any clarification would be super helpful.

Here is the link to my github repo: https://github.com/livmarx/zilliow-challenge

Comment: In the interpolated URL string you have `access_token=undefined` because in [your code](https://github.com/livmarx/zilliow-challenge/blob/0f80b59fa5b64bfddc84a38f9cdb3a5d0314f1f8/client/components/SearchBar.js#L31) (not in the example here) you have `access_token=${GITHUB_KEY}` instead of `access_token=${process.env.GITHUB_KEY}`

Comment: Hi! So, I tried changing them all to process.env.GITHUB_KEY and still getting undefined

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11104156/1207049). It means you have to pass the value to an environment variable in the _shell_ the node app is running from. `process.env` will be populated with the env. variables available for the shell at the time. You'd start your app e.g. by `export GITHUB_KEY="xxx" node server.js` in a Linux shell.

Comment: Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35317795/1207049) for a workaround for setting env variables at run time.