# Is it possible to judge npm script in a JavaScript file in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, npm, webpack

I have a config file in my vue.js + webpack + npm project

/plugins/http/GLOBAL_CONST.js

```
const GLOBAL_CONST = {}


GLOBAL_CONST.BASE_URL = "http://www.example.com/"  // "http://localhost:3000/"  

GLOBAL_CONST.BASE_API = "http://www.example:8000/"  //  "http://localhost:8000/"  

export default GLOBAL_CONST
```

I have a requirement, if I run `npm run dev`, the

```
GLOBAL_CONST.BASE_URL = "http://localhost:3000/"
GLOBAL_CONST.BASE_API = "http://localhost:8000/"
```

if I run `npm run build` it use:

```
GLOBAL_CONST.BASE_URL = "http://www.example.com/"  
GLOBAL_CONST.BASE_API = "http://www.example:8000/"
```

is it possible to make it come true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is commonly done with `if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')` (equals `true` for `npm run build`), so you could use that condition when setting `BASE_URL`:

```js
GLOBAL_CONST.BASE_URL = (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')
                      ? "http://www.example.com/"
                      : "http://localhost:3000/"
```

If using Vue CLI, the `NODE_ENV` environment variable is [automatically set](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html) for you during the build. Otherwise, you could [set it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11104028/process-env-node-env-is-undefined) yourself in your build script:

```js
// package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production node build.js",
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server [...]"
  }
}
```