# How to get random client's IP in NODEJS

Tags: node.js

i am working on a project in **NODE.JS** in which when user logged in,his area's weather is automatically shown on his dashboard.
According to my understanding,when a client comes:

1)His ip is traced for which m using *request-ip*.

2)Then according to this ip dimensions of his area can be determined.for this m using *satelize*.

3)Then on the basis of longitude and latitude,his area's weather can be predicted with the help of *forcast.io*.

problem is sending request to that middleware,m getting loopback ip.(localhost:3000).while i want to get any random client's ip.so that i can check whether my api is working correct or not.
here is my code:

```
router.get('/',function(req,res){

  var clientIp = requestIp.getClientIp(req); //inside middleware handle

  satelize.satelize({ip:clientIp}, function(err, geoData) { // if data is JSON, we may wrap it in js object 

    var obj = JSON.parse(geoData);

    forecast.get([obj.latitude, obj.longitude], function(err, weather) { 

      if(err) return console.dir(err); 

      console.log(weather);

    });

  }); 

});
```

Comment: show some code with what have you tried

Comment: router.get('/',function(req,res){
 var clientIp = requestIp.getClientIp(req); 
//inside middleware handle
satelize.satelize({ip:clientIp}, function(err, geoData) {
   // if data is JSON, we may wrap it in js object
 var obj = JSON.parse(geoData);
 
   forecast.get([obj.latitude, obj.longitude], function(err, weather) {
  if(err) return console.dir(err);
 console.log(weather);
});
 });
});

Comment: please edit your question with the content of the comment you wrote

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you'd like to use a random ip address when developing on your local machine. In order to do this, you'd have to set the clientIp variable based on your environment. You can use NODE_ENV for this, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16979503/2494649 for a nice explanation.

If you want to use an ip address of a random client, you will have to collect these yourself and set it as the clientIp. You could for instance set an array of random client ip's and use them randomly.

```
var randomIps = ['1.2.3.4', '5.6.7.8', '123.123.123.123'];
var clientIp;

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    // Select random IP address
  clientIp = randomIps[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomIps.length)];
} else {
  clientIp = requestIp.getClientIp(req); //inside middleware handle
}
```

You could use your app to save your client ip addresses to a datastore (anonymously) and use these addresses to provide a random ip address to the clientIp variable.