# Is there a way to display NODE_ENV from the command line?

Tags: node.js

Please, answers here all refer to a something called process.env.NODE_ENV, but `echo $process.env.NODE_ENV` from the command line did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you asking how to print an environment variable in your shell? Consult the docs for you shell.

Comment: As @SLaks says, consult the shell docs.  A typical example is "echo $NODE_ENV" but shells vary

Answer (score 61):

Use `echo $NODE_ENV`. The command line is a shell, probably bash and that's the bash syntax to print the value of an environment variable.

Comment: @thetrystero Based on your various comments, the environment variable probably hasn't been defined anywhere. What value are you expecting it to have? When and where are you attempting to set it? Also note that it is not a default variable for Node ([What is NODE_ENV in Express?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978256/what-is-node-env-in-express)).

Comment: it shows you nothing because the variable is empty, but it indeed does work.

Comment: I defined it by running the app using `$ NODE_ENV=production node app`

Comment: You should do `set NODE_ENV=<node env>` on Windows and `export NODE_ENV=<node env>` on unix-based OSes. `echo $NODE_ENV` worked for me.

Answer (score 45):

If you have defined `NODE_ENV` variable then you should be able to see this by typing `node` in the command prompt which will open the node cell and then type `process.env.NODE_ENV`.

To check the existing env variables .. type this .. `process.env`

Comment: I've run `NODE_ENV=production node app` from the command line, so this should set it to production correct? then in another terminal window within the same directory where i ran the above command, i enter the node REPL and type `process.env.NODE_ENV` but it returns undefined.

Comment: @thetrystero I have the same issue

Answer (score 24):

You call list all variables for Macs available for your project directory with...

```
printenv
```

I use this often to look for the NODE_ENV and other variables.

Comment: also works from a unix like shell on Windows too

Answer (score 16):

go to node REPL, and then give process.env.NODE_ENV and the variable process is scoped inside nodejs process, not in your shell process.

```
sk3037@saravana:~/src$ node
> process.env.
```

Comment: tried it. process.env.NODE_ENV in the repl returns undefined.

Comment: Wouldn't running it as `$ NODE_ENV=production node app` set the variable to `production` ?

Answer (score 7):

Setp-by-step windows CMD NODE_ENV:

1. > set NODE_ENV=my_node_env   (defines NODE_ENV)
2. > node (run node)
3. > process.env.NODE_ENV (show NODE_ENV)

After "set NODE_ENV" you can run the application, and it will use the set NODE_ENV. You can run your application with custom environment in [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) without problem.

Comment: setting it does not work for me in powershell: you should use $env:NODE_ENV="my_node_env"

Answer (score 4):

1. Find the Id of the process you are running by executing `ps aux | grep node`
2. Look at the environment variables used by that process by executing `less /proc/[your-id]/environ`

Answer (score 3):

To display the current node environment in windows, use:

```
> echo %NODE_ENV%
```

It wil output the environment on the command line like:

```
development
```

Comment: It prints "%NODE_ENV%" for me

Comment: It helps to find out when you set the env first. Next echo it . other wise it displays  same message %NODE_ENV% Try like this :- set NODE_ENV=production and then Echo it you will see the set env

Comment: @Pumych try $NODE_ENV

Comment: echo $NODE_ENV on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the NODE_ENV for process?

Here are some example.
Somewhere in code, you set the node environment to `"production"` or `"development"` or `"any thing you want"`.
And do some stuff according to your node environment.

```
process.env.NODE_ENV="production";

//others coding
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production")
{
  //useblabla log level.
  //use production log.
}
else if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "development")
{
  //useblabla log level.
  //use development log.

}
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV); //"production"
```

Comment: Yes, I do have these if statements in my app.js. I'm running the app using `$ NODE_ENV=production node app`

Comment: @thetrystero So still cann't you echo your NODE_ENV?

Answer (score 1):

Run `npm config get production`; if it's true, then it's in production.

Run `npm config get dev`; if it's true, then it's in development.

Run `npm config ls -l` to view all default cli configs value.

Answer (score 0):

I did this by defining the production environment in my scripts in the package.json file, and based on the script that I run, console.log() will print out the name of the environment:

```js
// ... other package.json stuff
"scripts": {
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon app.js",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production nodemon app.js"
 },
```

If I run `npm start` the value of process.env.NODE_ENV will be production, whereas if I run `npm run dev`, it's value will be development.