# How to set ASP.NET 5 environment variables on production environment

Tags: environment-variables, asp.net-core

In Visual Studio 2015 you set the following variable in project properties: **ASPNET_ENV**. If you set it to development then you can use:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseErrorPage();
    }
 }
```

IsDevelopment method will check **ASPNET_ENV** environment variable. Now this is all good on development while you are in Visual Studio 2015. When you publish the web application to IIS on a production server how can you set the value for **ASPNET_ENV**?

My server is Windows Server 2012

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asp.net 5 publish to IIS, setting ASPNET\_ENV Variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31049152/asp-net-5-publish-to-iis-setting-aspnet-env-variables)

Comment: Take a look at the following: http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/environments.html -- in particular, pay attention to the NOTE that indicates that web server needs to be restarted for changes in this area to take effect.

Comment: @Amit it is not because the answer given their doesn't make sense

Comment: @DavidTansey there is no mention in the document on how to do it? where to set the variable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using IIS to host your application, it's possible to set the environment variables in your `web.config`file like this:

```
<aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false">
    <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="QA" />
        <environmentVariable name="AnotherVariable" value="My Value" />
    </environmentVariables>
</aspNetCore>
```

Comment: Please correct the indentation in your markdown so the closing tag (`</aspNetCore>`) is included as code, and the `environmentVariables` subsection is nicely indented.  I would have done it myself but it doesn't count as sufficient characters to allow the edit.

Answer (score 8):

This is how to set the environment variable on Windows:

1. On your server, right click 'Computer' or 'My Computer' and click on 'Properties'.
2. Go to 'Advanced System Settings'.
3. Click on 'Environment Variables' in the Advanced tab.
4. Add a new System Variable with the name `ASPNET_ENV` (RC1) or `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` (RC2, RTM and Above) and a value of `Production`, `Staging`, `Development` or whatever you want.
5. A reboot of your site may be required.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31228947/how-to-determine-the-asp-net-5-environment-in-my-gulpfile-js/31728868) answer for how to read the environment variable from gulpfile.js.

Comment: As of RC1, environment variable was changed to Hosting:Environment.

Comment: @GradyWerner See https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/706#issuecomment-160450913

Comment: A reboot to put a new System envrionment variable ?? is this true ?

Comment: @DonDon I meant a reboot of the site. I haven't tested. I've updated the answer to clarify.

Comment: Had to reboot the machine to take the changes in effect.

Comment: As noted in the answer, RC2 and later uses  ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT  (without the colon)