# How to conditionally execute javascript code based on the host environment or the debug/release mode of an asp.net core project?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

In a ASP.NET Core 3.1 project, I conditionally execute c# code based on the host environment, for example:

```
if (this.webHostEnvironment.IsProduction())
{
   // execute code only when ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT is not Development
}
```

Elsewhere `#if DEBUG` is used to distinguish between debug and release modes:

```
#if DEBUG
   ...
#else
   ...
#endif
```

The project also contains javascript code. Is there a way to apply any of the above methods to the javascript code? For example, in the following situation:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor() {        
        this.checkEvery = 10;        // DEBUG: 30    RELEASE: 10
        this.checkDuration = 'm';    // DEBUG: 's'   RELEASE: 'm'
    }
}
```

If not, is there any other way to achieve this?

**UPDATE:**
As @MattMorgan commented a possible solution would be to have a (global) javascript variable to hold the current environment (Development, Staging, Production) or mode (Debug, Release).

Nevertheless, the key points here are automation and consistency. If `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is set to `Production` the javascript code should follow suit automatically.

Comment: Is this answer helpful?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728868/3084820

Comment: @MattMorgan Very nice idea but that answer is coupled to Nodejs (I think). My project runs vanilla javascript where `require` and `process` are not defined.

Comment: And there's no way to set an environment variable in the deployed javascript?  That seems like the key.

Comment: @MattMorgan Excellent suggestion. I think I've found a solution -will post it after testing.

Answer (score 0):

The following markup in can be found in `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<environment include="Development">
   ...
</environment>

<environment exclude="Development">
   ...
</environment>
```

Since it's driven by `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` it can be used to conditionally load js configuration file, for example:

```
<environment include="Development">
  <script src="~/js/global_dev.js"></script>
</environment>

<environment exclude="Development">
  <script src="~/js/global.js"></script>
</environment>
```

`global_dev.js` and `global.js` may define global `environment` variable, for example in `global.js`:

```
var environment = 'Production';
```

which nicely answers the question.