# What is process.env.NODE_ENV

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3

```
var config = require('env/' + process.env.NODE_ENV),
```

Trying to integrate my upload system using dropzone js and aws in nodejs. But the first line already confused me. Where does that thing coming from and what does it means?

https://gist.github.com/francolaiuppa/76f4b60cd46a15d325cf

Comment: Possible Dup of [What is NODE_ENV in Express?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978256/what-is-node-env-in-express)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the github link you have shared, it is a controller code in **express.js**

So considering that

`process.env.NODE_ENV` will return the value of environment variable **NODE_ENV** set by **express.js**