# TypeScript definitions for process.env.NODE_ENV?

Tags: typescript

Is there a project with TypeScript definitions for "process" variable to use process.env.NODE_ENV? Couldn't find anywhere.

Comment: Nothing worked for my development environment, so I just used https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv package, and now it works.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The definitions for the 'process' variable can be  found in default node.js d.ts from definitely typed and added in your typings.json like this:

```
"node": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/node/node.d.ts"
```

I do not think there are any definitions for the particular NODE_ENV variable. As it is just a convention (widely used by express [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978256/what-is-node-env-in-express)) and node.js itself does not care about that specific environment variable.

Comment: Note that this won't play very nice with the `webpack-env` DefinitelyTyped

Answer (score 46):

**Update for Node 8**:

Now `env` is declared as `ProcessEnv` in [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/fd7bea617cc47ffd252bf90a477fcf6a6b6c3ba5/types/node/index.d.ts#L438).

```
env: ProcessEnv;

export interface ProcessEnv {
    [key: string]: string | undefined;
}
```

TypeScript 2 supports npm package type definitions for node. It currently uses the DefinitivelyTyped node.d.ts.

```
npm install --save-dev @types/node
```

**Pre Node 8 version**:

process [`env` is declared as `any` in DefinitelyTyped node.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/f470e7569e7046c62866f57bc4fea56ba79975d5/node/node.d.ts#L332).

```
env: any;
```

Comment: Since node.v8 env is declared as ProcessEnv in DefinitelyTyped node.d.ts

Comment: @Sandokan El Cojo: Nice one. Updated based on your comment.

Comment: For anyone looking:

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node/v8/index.d.ts#L574

Comment: Could you give link to repo with this stuff? I copied but its not work, I got error: `Property 'REDIS_SESSION_SECRET' is missing in type 'ProcessEnv' but required in type 'ProcessEnv'. [2741]` my code is `const env: ProcessEnv = process.env`

Comment: Thanks this worked for me: npm install --save-dev @types/node

Answer (score 8):

just add before use process.env.NODE_ENV

```
declare var process : {
  env: {
    NODE_ENV: string
  }
}
```

Comment: this is obsoleted approach, please check new approach (`@types/node`) in other answers

Answer (score 7):

### To add the node definitions in TypeScript 3+

Use the types from Definitely Typed via npm/yarn:

```sh
# Install the latest
npm install --save-dev @types/node
# or
yarn add @types/node --dev

# To install the right types for your version of node (e.g. 12 here)
npm install --save-dev @types/node@^12
yarn add @types/node@^12 --dev
```

With your types available, the object `process.env` should be available in your code.

### Extending `process.env`

You can use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to add new values to `process.env`. Create a new `d.ts` file in your project, then add:

```
declare global {
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface ProcessEnv {
      NODE_ENV?: string
    }
  }
}
```

This will let you write `process.env.NODE_ENV`. I'd recommend keeping the ? in unless you have validation that it's set somewhere in the library.

Comment: Should the types be installed as a devDependency?

Comment: Yes, they should be

Comment: For make it work i've required to add: export {} at the file.

Answer (score 4):

```
declare namespace NodeJS {
  interface ProcessEnv {
    [key: string]: string | undefined
    NODE_ENV?: 'development' | 'production' | 'test'
  }
}
```

put the code above in your file `global.d.ts`

Answer (score 2):

If your are using `create-react-app your-app-test --template typescript`
then already exist a file to set your environment variables.

file name: `react-app-env.d.ts` located at `src` folder.

then you can set in that file your custom `env` variables with this template:

```
/// <reference types="react-scripts" />
declare global {
    namespace NodeJS {
      interface ProcessEnv {
        GITHUB_AUTH_TOKEN: string;
        NODE_ENV: 'development' | 'production';
        PORT?: string;
        PWD: string;
      }
    }
  }
  
  // If this file has no import/export statements (i.e. is a script)
  // convert it into a module by adding an empty export statement.
  export {}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error in VSCode, maybe you just need to restart it.