# Accessing process.env in TypeScript. Dot notation doesn't work

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm setting in scripts: `"start": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon dist/Server.js"`
then trying to read `NODE_ENV` in code, both dot and bracket notation return `undefined`:

I have next configurations:
"@types/node": "^8.0.53"
 "typescript": "^2.6.1"
  node 8.9.1 installed locally

Doesn't seems like process.env even have NODE_ENV after I console.log it.
`console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);`
`console.log(process.env["NODE_ENV"]);` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39769388/2110448)
 What's wrong with it ?.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post how you access the NODE_ENV variable in your code, but this works fine for me:

package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon test.js"
  }
```

test.js

```
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)
```

Result of running `npm test`:

```
[nodemon] 1.12.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node test.js`
development
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

(I'm using node v7.10.1, but I'd expect this to work on any version)

Comment: I know it should work you right. I tried all process.env.NODE_ENV, process.env["NODE_ENV"]. As I know if NODE_ENV not specified it will fall do default `development`, try set test instead of dev, see if it work out for you.

Comment: Your example works fine, that something interfering setting env in my code.