# NODE_ENV variable in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I am a beginner in Node and I see the following code in my project:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV
```

What is `NODE_ENV` and how can I get access to it or change it? It seems to pick up some values but don't know from where is it getting picked up.

Please let me know.

Comment: Check your operating system's environment variables

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9204973 for ways `NODE_ENV` can be set

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is NODE\_ENV in Express?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978256/what-is-node-env-in-express)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NODE_ENV` is the name of an [environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable), and you can access and change it in your shell Ex: `export NODE_ENV=development` , you can change it when running your process, Ex: `NODE_ENV=production node application.js`, or you can change it in one of your [shell's configuration files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell#Configuration_files).