# Serving image paths with express js

Tags: node.js, express

I have on the server side a expres js. I'm serving images with:

```
app.use('/static', express.static(out_path));
```

On some querys the server return image paths. So in production that would be

```
https://<myApp>.com/static/<image_name>
```

Since I need also a dev environment the path would be

```
http://localhost:port/static/<image_name>
```

Is there an elegant solution to this problem? I could use a config or something like that, but perhaps there exist a better solution.

Thanks and best reagards

Answer (score 0):

You can set an environment variable ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978256/what-is-node-env-in-express)) like NODE_ENV and then parse this variable to distinguish what path you should serve. Something like:

```
var SITE_PATH = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'prod-path' : 'dev-path';
```