# grouping express middlewares in array for app.use

Tags: node.js

```
import express from 'express'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import api from 'routes'
import timeout from 'connect-timeout'
import haltOnTimeout from 'middlewares/haltOnTimeout'
import compression from 'compression'
import helmet from 'helmet'
import path from 'path'

const app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(timeout(3000))
app.use(haltOnTimeout)

app.use(compression()) // production
app.use(helmet()) // production

app.use('/api', api)

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(`${__dirname}/../../client/build`))) // production

export default app
```

I have my `app.js` like this.

now I'm going to deploy my app on aws.

In order to do this,

I want to divide my middlewares into array and execute it based on environment.

For example,

```
const middlewares = [
  bodyParser.json(),
  bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }),
  timeout(3000),
  ...
]

const productionMiddlewares = [
  compression(),
  helmet()
  ...
]
```

Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answare is inspired by [sailsjs](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails)

You can have two config file and a structure like this

```
root
  |-app.js
  |-package.json
  |-bootstrapper.js
  |-config
     |- middleware.js
```

Basically, you will write your middleware divided by environment in the `middleware.js` file, the bootstrapper.js file will hold the logic mount the middleware into the express application, the bootstrapper can use the [NODE_ENV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978256/what-is-node-env-in-express) variable to choose which middleware set to mount. The bootstrapper will be then called by your app.js during startup.

---

```
//app.js
import express from 'express'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import api from 'routes' 
import timeout from 'connect-timeout'
import haltOnTimeout from 'middlewares/haltOnTimeout'
import compression from 'compression'
import helmet from 'helmet'
import path from 'path'
import bootstrapper from 'bootstrap'

const app = express()

bootstrap.bootMiddleware(app)

app.use('/api', api)
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(`${__dirname}/../../client/build`))) // production

export default app
```

In your middleware.js file you define the middlewares and the order in which you have to mount them, you will have different file based on your environment.

```
// */middleware.js
exports.module = {
   'dev_middlewares' : [
      'bodypParserJson',
       // other middlewares
      'helmet'
   ],
   'prod_middlewares' : [
      'bodypParserJson',
       // other middlewares
      'helmet'
   ],
   'helmet' : helmet(),
   'bodypParserJson': bodyParser.json()
}
```

The bootstrapper then will have the function to mount the appropriate middlewares

```
// bootstrapper
function loadMiddleware(app, list, middlewareConf){
  _.foreach(middlewareName => {
     app.use(middlewareConf[middlewareName])
  })
}

function bootMiddleware(app){
   let env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev';
   var middlewareConf = require('./config/middleware')
   if(env==='dev') {
      loadMiddleware(app, dev_middleware, middlewareConf)
   } else {
      loadMiddleware(app, prod_middleware, middlewareConf)
   }
}
export bootMiddleware
```

Comment: Most structured and elegant way to bootstrap an app, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Standard way

```
app.configure('development', function() {
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true })); 
});

app.configure('production', function() {
  app.use(express.errorHandler()); 
});
```

---

Simple way

```
var middlewares= process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production' ? [compression, ...] : [some-other];
middlewares.forEach((middleware) => app.use(middleware));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the required array and register the middleware. For example:

```
for (var m in (app.get('env') === 'production' ? productionMiddlewares : middlewares)) {
    app.use(m)
}
```

Comment: Thanks too stdob!