# NPM Watch for css changes not working on on npm run start

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, sass

So during my npm run start it's not catching any changes to the scss files which get compiled into a css file.  The scss works just fine when I run npm run build, but it's not catching any css changes.  I have added css script, that I would also run off to the side, however, that isn't working either.  Do you all have any idea on how to resolve this?  Or do you any of you have a working webpack set up that catches scss changes with npm run start?

I actually see the terminal recompile when I make the changes, so I know that it's being caught.  This is a react app fyi.  Here is my webpack config file (which works during run build)

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
module.exports = {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',

    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html',
            filename: "./index.html"
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
            // both options are optional
            filename: "/static/cs/styles.css",
            chunkFilename: "styles.css"
        })


    ],

    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'static/js/bundle.js'
    },
    module: {

        rules: [

            {
                test: /\.s?css$/,
                use: [
                    "style-loader",
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    "css-loader",
                    "sass-loader"
                ]
            },

            {
                use: { loader: 'babel-loader' },
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            outputPath: '',
                        },
                    }

                ]
            },


        ]
    },

    devServer: {

        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),

    },


}
```

And here is my scripts

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot ",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "build-task:scss-compile": "node-sass-chokidar --source-map true src/scss/ -o dist/css",
    "build-task:autoprefixer": "postcss dist/css/*.css --use autoprefixer -d dist/css",
    "sass:build": "npm-run-all -p build-task:*",
    "sass:watch": "chokidar 'src/styles/*.scss' -c 'npm run sass:build'",
    "dev": "npm-run-all -p sass:*",
    "css": "node-sass src/styles/styles.scss -o dist",
    "css:watch": "npm run css && node-sass src/styles/styles.scss -wo dist"
  },
```

Comment: try using `npm run dev` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, prepend `NODE_ENV=development` to your start script:

```js
{
//...
    "start": "NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot ",
//...
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16979503/4920630) on StackOverflow to read more about node environment variables.

Now, in production, you want to **extract** the css out of the created bundle and put it in a separate `.css` file. In `development` you want to just inject it inline so you have benefits like hot reloading. In your case, you first extract the css and *then* try to inject it. Which means that there is nothing to inject anymore by the `style-loader` because all styles have been extracted already.

Use `process.env.NODE_ENV` to read which environment you are in (which reads the `NODE_ENV` value in your npm script). Based on that, add `style-loader` OR `MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader`.

```
        {
            test: /\.s?css$/,
            use: [
                process.env.NODE_ENV === development ?"style-loader": MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                "css-loader",
                "sass-loader"
            ]
        },
```

Don't forget to only add `MiniCssExtractPlugin` to your plugins array if you are in a production environment. A way to do this is:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

// Create a shortcut, returns true if you're NODE_ENV is set to development
const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';

// Let's wait with exporting, and first assign the config object to a variable:
const config = {
    // ...    
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html',
            filename: "./index.html"
        }),

    ],
    // ...    
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.s?css$/,
                use: [
                    isDev ? "style-loader" : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    "css-loader",
                    "sass-loader"
                ]
            },
        // ...   

        ]
    },
    // ...   
}

// if NOT in development, push `MiniCssExtractPlugin` to plugin array
if (!isDev) {
    config.plugins.push(
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
            // both options are optional
            filename: "/static/cs/styles.css",
            chunkFilename: "styles.css"
        })
    )
}

module.exports = config;
```

There are way better ways to split development configuration from production. Many articles - like [this one](https://simonsmith.io/organising-webpack-config-environments) for example - explain ways how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This issue resolved for me after running the react-script command with adminitstative permission:

Linux:

```
sudo npm start
```

Windows:

> Right Click on cmd. Then, click on run as administrator