# How to access my React app with node backend in local network?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, networking

I created a react app on my MacBook and I access it with `http://localhost:3000`.
Additionally I run an nodejs express mysql server on `http://localhost:5000`.
When I open the IP address with port 3000 in the browser of my Windows 10 laptop in the same network (`http://192.166.15.85:3000`) I see my app, but the console throws an network error for my backend, because it can not access `http://localhost:5000`.
I hard coded the `axios.get()` in the frontend to call `http://localhost:5000`, what is fine for my MacBook. But for the Windows 10 laptop I'd need the ip address instead.
How can I handle this?

The error is:

```
GET http://localhost:5000/get_users net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
Error: Network Error
   at: createError(createError.js:16)
   at: XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:91)
```

Comment: Could you post the error you get? I assume it's link to [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: I updated the question. I think it is linked to localhost not existing at the windows laptop. When I replace localhost with the ip it works

Comment: If you try to access the backend from your Windows computer, you need to replace localhost with the ip address

Comment: Sure, and know the question: How can I handle this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you add `app.use(cors())` in your backend it will work
[cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

Comment: That's already in my backend. I'm sure, if I replace localhost with the ip in my api call in the frontend, it will work. But couldn't that be more flexible (hat's my original question). When I deploy my app to my server, I'll have the same issues with ip and / or localhost.

Comment: Ok I understand your issue now. You can access `process.env.NODE_ENV` to test if you're in development or production: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16979503/10333882

Comment: I checked the `process.env.NODE_ENV` on my MacBook and on my windows laptop. For both it is `development`. Thus, that couldn't be the trigger like `process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? 'localhost' : '192.166.15.85'`

Comment: You can change the NODE_ENV value like this: `NODE_ENV=mac-development node app.js` and `NODE_ENV=windows-development node app.js`. Hope this helps

Comment: I set and verified the `NODE_ENV` to production on the windows laptop, but it prints development. I think, this is because I don't run the app on the windows machine. I access it trough the IP and the app runs on the MacBook, thus it displays the variable of the machine where it runs.

Comment: Yes you're right, you could try to do a similar thing with `window.location.hostname`

Comment: That's it. If you'll post it as an answer, I'll accept it. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can get the current hostname by using `window.location.hostname` and then conditionally change the url

Comment: Geez! Duh! Just basic JavaScript. So simple. ChatGPT really failed me on this one. Gracias