# Is NestJS using NODE_ENV? Is it recommended to set it?

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs, environment, nodeenv

I am using [NestJS](https://nestjs.com/) and I am new to it.

I have read that [`NODE_ENV` is an environment variable that specifies the environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978256/what-is-node-env-and-how-to-use-it-in-express), introduced by [Express](http://expressjs.com/).

Since NestJS is based on Express, I don't know if `NODE_ENV` is also relevant for NestJS.

Is it still recommended to set `NODE_ENV` when using NestJS? Or is it not necessary for NestJS?

Answer (score 2):

Setting environment variables is up to your needs, and for `NODE_ENV` if your application doesn't' support any kind of several environment like prod, dev.. than you're not necessary to add it.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are going to use environment variables, make sure to read this:

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration

It will save you a lot of trouble!