# How to set NODE_ENV so that .env.development.local is used instead of .env?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dotenv

I'm having issues getting dotenv to use the `.env.development.local` or `.env.development` file when starting in development mode. It only ever uses `.env`.

My package.json:

```
{
    "name": "server",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "webpack",
        "start": "nodemon src/index.js"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.21.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
        "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
        "copy-webpack-plugin": "^11.0.0",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
        "webpack": "^5.75.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
        "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
        "express": "^4.18.2",
        "mongoose": "^6.9.0"
    }
}
```

Understanding of the heirarchy is as so:

```
.env.development.local > .env.local > .env.development > .env
```

With a few additional I have omitted which I don't plan to use.

I have been told that the issue is I need to specify the `NODE_ENV` somewhere in the start script but I have yet to find any documentation or guide showing me how to do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is NODE\_ENV and how to use it in Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978256/what-is-node-env-and-how-to-use-it-in-express)

Comment: @Ouroborus it actually does but how do I do the part that mentions that one should persist the setting of the variable so that it doesn't lose it on next PC shutdown/restart. It doesn't go into that. It offers a temporary solution via setting it in command line.

Would it be referring to a Windows environment variable? My dev PC is windows.

Comment: At this point, you'd go back to Google and search something like "windows set env variable"

Comment: I know how to set the windows environment variable, my question was is THAT what I need to do to make it persist?

Comment: Yes, that's how you set environment variables in Windows so that they persist through a reboot. If you set them by command or script, they usually last as long as that session lasts. The general case is that, when something talks about "environment variables", this is what they're talking about. They're typically exposed in the language in some way (such as `process.env` in Node) but they originally come from the system or shell.